# Magento Cart empty after login @ checkout /w Safari browser and Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: checkout, cart, session

We have this problem. Customers have 3 products in cart. Then go to checkout & log-in: after login their cart is empty! Not good for conversion.

I see some questions actually requesting this functionality- but none that address our issue. Persistent shopping cart is set to NO

**Question:** Is there a setting to prevent the cart from being emptied after login?

Basically what we want is that no-matter-what the situation: the cart a user is "actively" populating (read: now) is always the cart. No merging, no resetting. Just use the cart as-is

[image]

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party checkout modules? Do you have a FPC?

Comment: No checkout ones. Yes we use a FPC< but it only caches cms_index* and catalog/product ...

Comment: disable fpc and see how it goes, if it persists, look further, if it is gone, change your fpc configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error related to cookie settings not working on Safari

After investigation all customers with this problem were using Safari

[Customers couldn't login from Safari In magento 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49134/customers-couldnt-login-from-safari-in-magento-1-9/63089#63089)

Very annoying. Reported as bug.