# Security Patch SUPEE-9767 - Possible issues?

Tags: magento-1, security, patches, supee-9767

A new security patch is out for Magento 1, addressing 16 APPSEC issues: https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-9767

**Seven of the vulnerabilities score 8.0 or higher for CVSSv3 Severity**, and they are being exploited in the wild, so this is a critical patch. Sites can apply **SUPEE-9767**, or update to the new release CE 1.9.3.3 / EE 1.14.3.3.

**What are common issues or pitfalls to watch out for when applying SUPEE-9767?**

---

### UPDATE 2017-07-12:

Magento has released [SUPEE-9767 V2](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2034) and [CE 1.9.3.4](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2033) to address many of the issues from the initial patch. If you applied V1, you should revert and then apply V2. If you haven't patched yet, just apply V2, and most of the issues brought up here will not be relevant.

Comment: "Seven of the vulnerabilities score 8.0 or higher for CVSSv3 Severity, and they are being exploited in the wild, so this is a critical patch."  I just wanted to check, the "attacker" needs to get into admin to do any of these exploits?

Comment: yes, you must have admin access to exploit...

Comment: The patch doesn't seem to stop the common brute-force endpoint though, (i.e. /rss/order/new) which seems to be the most common way botters are attempting to gain access to admin areas?

Comment: I use this for RSS @RickyOdinMatthews  in .htaccess

 
`RewriteRule ^/?(index.phprss|index.php/rss/catalog|index.php/rss/order|rss/catalog|rss/order).*$ /no-route [R=301,L,NC]`

Comment: @RichardFeraro I use nginx, but already use a similar solution. I've noticed bots typically scan for, and brute force these endpoints though.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Here's my overview of the patch after digging into it

**TIME SAVER** : Experius provides a **patch helper that helps you finding the files in custom themes, custom modules or local overwrites that also might need to be patched manually**, you can find it here: https://github.com/experius/Magento-1-Experius-Patch-Helper#magento

### Checkout form keys

As said in the other post, this patch adds form keys to the following forms:

**Shipping cart form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
```

**Multishipping billing checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
```

**Multishipping shipping checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
```

**Multishipping addresses checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
```

**Billing checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

**Shipping checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
```

**Payment checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
```

**Shipping method checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
```

**Persistent Billing checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

On top of that the following JS files have been updated to be compatible with that change:

- `js/varien/payment.js`
- `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js`

**What to do:**

If you're using with custom versions of those templates you'll have to update them by adding the following code into them:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

If you're using a 3rd party checkout module, you'll have to get in touch with them so they can provide an updated version of their module.

Also if you have custom versions of the previously listed JS files, you'll have to update them too.

**SAVE YOUR TIME**:

Fabian Schmengler wrote a nice little script to update all those things for you, you can find it here:

https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b

**IMPORTANT NOTE** : the checkout formkey validation can be changed in the backend via a new config field under **System > Configuration > Admin > Security > Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout** . **THIS IS NOT ENABLED BY DEFAULT** so you'll have to enable it to benefit from this security feature!!! Note that you'll get a notice in the backend if it's not enabled.

### Image Upload callback

The image gallery controller has been updated to add a validation callback.

**What to do**

If you're using a custom module that does image upload with code that looks like this:

```
        $uploader = new Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader('image');
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
        $uploader->addValidateCallback('catalog_product_image',
            Mage::helper('catalog/image'), 'validateUploadFile');
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
```

I strongly suggest you update that code by adding the following piece after it:

```
        $uploader->addValidateCallback(
            Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image::NAME,
            Mage::getModel('core/file_validator_image'),
            'validate'
        );
```

### Symlinks

This patch removes the system configuration field that allows you to allow template symlinks in the backend. It used to be under **System > Configuration > Developer > Template > Allow Symlinks** . Now the entire Template section is gone.

On top of that, that field is now disabled by default via the `app/etc/config.xml`

The funny thing here is that you'll get a notice in the backend if you have that configuration field enabled prior to the patch but you won't be able to disable it as the field is gone.

Only way of doing it is by running the following SQL query

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 0 WHERE path = "dev/template/allow_symlink";
```

**Clarification**

First I strongly suggest you check those two posts that will help you understand the purpose of that Symlink modification:

- From Peter O'Collaghan: https://peterocallaghan.co.uk/2017/06/appsec-1281-dangerous-symlinks/
- From Max Chadwick: https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/what-allow-symlinks-actually-does

[This modification is really about calling uploadable content (like images) via template directives.](https://twitter.com/piotrekkaminski/status/870000993588568064)

[The issue related to symlinks is exploitable only with admin access and Magento added some more protection around image uploads as well.](https://twitter.com/piotrekkaminski/status/870020878586617857)

[Please note that they are some protections against known way to exploit it in addition to the setting itself.](https://twitter.com/piotrekkaminski/status/870041664747732992)

**What to do**: if like me, you're using modman or composer with template symlinks, you're gonna face some issues. I'm still trying to find out what's the best thing to do here apart from dealing with SQL queries.

Main post regarding this issue: [SUPEE-9767, modman and symlinks](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/176952/2380)

### List of possible issues

V2 was released since that original post. Don't forget to upgrade

#### Bugs

The word 'confirmed' is used for confirmed bugs. If it's not there, that means it could be a bug but hasn't been confirmed yet.

- [Customer registration fails at checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177125/2380)  CONFIRMED & FIXED IN V2
- [PHP7 and EE bug](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177036/2380) CONFIRMED
- [Bug with EE, FPC and Design Exceptions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/177658/2380) CONFIRMED
- [Add to cart and cookie bug in EE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/177942/2380) CONFIRMED
- [Multishipping broken after patch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/177681/2380) CONFIRMED
- [Missing bug fix in `head-simple.phtml`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176902/2380) CONFIRMED & FIXED IN V2
- [Admin Symlink warning is not displayed on 1.9.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176900/2380) CONFIRMED & FIXED IN V2
- [Watermark get black background when transparent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/177005/2380) CONFIRMED & FIXED IN V2
- [Unable to upgrade via Magento Connect](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/177070/2380)
- [Infinite redirect loop on 1.6.0.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/177256/2380)

#### Hunk Failed Issues

Note that all those issues could be simply because you modified the original file, to double check that this is not the case:

- Backup the file where you get the Hunk Failed error
- Download the original file from your Magento version
- Compare both files

If files are different you'll have to apply the patch with the original file then reapply your custom changes the clean way such as:

- custom template in a custom theme folder
- `local.xml`
- app/code/local file

If files are not different then this is either a permission issue or a "bug" in the patch.

- [patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
  Hunk #1 FAILED at 36.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/176946/2380)
- [patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml Hunk #1 FAILED at 225.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/176886/2380)
- [patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php
  Hunk #6 FAILED at 1093.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/176933/2380)
- [patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml Hunk #3 FAILED at 1355.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/176981/2380)
- [patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
  Hunk #1 FAILED at 500.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/176995/2380)
- [Hunk failed on 1.8.0.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/177034/2380)

Comment: Great info... Raphael

Comment: If using generic magento checkout, the five step one. No need to make changes right?

Comment: @Icon nope . To double check use the tool I referenced at the top of my answer

Comment: anybody having issues with login through Safari? $this->renewSession(); is responsible(if removed the login works on all browsers), I have tried looking around for solutions: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49134/customers-couldnt-login-from-safari-in-magento-1-9 but the ones mentioned only work by removing  $this->renewSession(); Any ideas?

Comment: @KalvinKlien not sure if patch related. Did it work before the patch ?

Comment: It worked pre-patch, but after patch: static login pages worked, ajax logins stopped working(i did add formkey everywhere, even ajax login). Seems like removing $this->renewSession() from setCustomerAsLoggedIn() works. Just dont know what the effect of it going to be.

Comment: @KalvinKlien maybe you have a local overwrite could you use the tool I posted at the top of my answer to double check ?

Comment: just to add to the list of "other issues": it appears that https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167616/session-validation-failure-in-magento-1-ee-v-1-14-3-x-and-ce-1-9-3-x is not fixed in the latest version as well

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism How can i update security Patches by SSH on wamp localhost.

Comment: @Rathinam please create a new question ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/177560/51361

Comment: Another addition to the list: the patch breaks multishipping for the default theme https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177681/supee-9767-patch-ce-1-9-3-3-checkout-form-validation-breaks-multishipping-in-d

Comment: @AadMathijssen was about to add it to the list, thanks for that

Comment: In Magento CE 1.9.2.4 the Patch is creating .orig files for those files patched with "Hunk #x succeeded" messages in applied.patches.list. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408856/3755991

Comment: Can anyone confirm that the Patch breaks the function to add a product (on product list page) to the wishlist when you are not logged in (using Magento CE 1.9.2.4)? Before the patch the product was added after a successful login. Now only the wishlist appears without any message.

Comment: After apply SUPEE-9767 system configuration saves shipping config and payment config not working. any idea?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Great answer! Maybe you can improve it even further by updating this statement (I guess you are no longer trying to find out what's the best thing to do):"What to do: if like me, you're using modman or composer with template symlinks, you're gonna face some issues. I'm still trying to find out what's the best thing to do here apart from dealing with SQL queries.".

Comment: 'Watermark get black background when transparent' - can confirm this one is  correct.  This happens when you upload any transparent png in cms

Comment: An interesting change because of the Image Upload callback which was added, is that all jpeg images which are uploaded, now almost double in filesize. This is because the quality param in the imagejpeg function is hardcoded to 100. I understand why they do it like this, as to not decrease the quality of the image, but it results in significant bigger filesizes unfortunately :(

Answer (score 44):

### Issue1: form_key invalid at checkout onepage

Magento add `form_key` at most of the forms.

if you have `using default onepage and using  custom theme`, then you will  start  getting **`form_key` issue at checkout each step **;

you should add  form key at ***`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>`***

to form of each  checkout step files if below files exits,

- **`app/design/frontend/[Your_Package]/[YOUR_THEME]/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`**
- ***`app/design/frontend/[Your_Package]/[YOUR_THEME]/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml`***
- ***`app/design/frontend/[Your_Package]/[YOUR_THEME]/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml`***
- ***`app/design/frontend/[Your_Package]/[YOUR_THEME]/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml`***

if the template files are ***calling from base theme*** then it does not create problem.***Because patch will automatically update those files.***

Also note:  ***`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>`*** should always inside  of  form tag

> ```
>  <form action="" .....>
>      <fieldset>
>       .......
>        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
>      </fieldset>
>  </form>
> ```

** If you using Magento multi-shipping checkout then need to done at

below files:

### Issue2: form_key issue to Shipping estimation form at cart page:

Add form_key at estimates shipping form at cart page

Then must add form key  ***`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>`***

at *`app/design/frontend/{Your_Package}/{YOUR_THEME]/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`*

### Issue3: Magento onepage checkout opcheckout.js error

If you using *default onepage checkout* and have ***`opcheckout.js`***  then  should check

`if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]' || elements[i].name == 'form_key') {`is  available at  ***opcheckout.js***

If not exits then replace

> if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]') {

**with**

> if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]' || elements[i].name ==
>   'form_key') {

For case of issue1,issue2, issue3,  Issue can fix easily by  using @FabianSchmengler 's   script [add-checkout-form-key.sh](https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b). ***It will fix the issue on  your receptive theme files***

### Issue4: Invalid form key  after customer login when Mage_Customer_Model_Session rewrite

If `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` class rewrite  or have called from

`app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php` then you may be get  form_key issue  when we set a customer for the session using `setCustomerAsLoggedIn()` /or after a customer set at session .

In  this case, you must be   add

> Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->renewFormKey();

at  ***setCustomerAsLoggedIn()***  before call of

`Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));`

```
  public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
    {
        $this->setCustomer($customer);
        $this->renewSession();
        // add this  for patch -9767
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->renewFormKey();
       // end this for patch 9767
        Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
        return $this;
    }
```

**Issue5: Form_key issue after logout**

After *logout customer from session*, you may be  start session issue if 
If `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` class rewrite  or have called from

`app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php`

In those same need for this case:

```
   protected function _logout()
    {
        $this->setId(null);
        $this->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
        $this->getCookie()->delete($this->getSessionName());
// add this  for patch -9767
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->renewFormKey();
        return $this;
    }
```

---

### **Recommendation:**

**Recommendation1:**
*For fixed the issue of supee-9767*, you can use the patch https://github.com/experius/Magento-1-Experius-Patch-Helper

This is one best solution for now.

**Note**, before do that I am strongly recommended to  take ***files and database backup or full system backup.***

---

**Recommendation2:  Use patch feature on your ONESTEP CHECKOUT**

We know that patch supee-9767 release for security purpose, the if you using  **ONESTEP CHECKOUT then you should add form_key  validation to SAVE action of your onestep checkout controller**.

Suppose for save shipping method details, your onestep checkout have using
saveShippingmethod() Then on this you should add

```
if ($this->isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled() && !$this->_validateFormKey()) {
           return;
      }
```

Also on youmust add form key  ***`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>`***  at your onestep checkout phtml files respective section

Some related link

https://peterocallaghan.co.uk/2017/06/appsec-1281-dangerous-symlinks/

Comment: Nice and quick one-liner to find your custom template files for the form key in checkout; find app/design/frontend | grep -E "checkout/onepage/(billing|payment|shipping|shipping_method).phtml" | grep -v "base/default" | grep -v "rwd/default"

Comment: or update them immediately with a slightly longer one liner: https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b

Comment: that is @FabianSchmengler magic !!! :)

Comment: @FabianSchmengler awesome, that worked!

Comment: I am testing this on a default install with no extended themes and onestep checkout still seems to be broken when form key validation on checkout is enabled.

Comment: i got problem at payment method in onepagecheckout. in my theme don't have the opcheckout.js file.what is the solution for resolve the error?

Comment: Have rewrite homepage controller.php?

Comment: If you have onestep checkout then you should add form_key validation at each action of your page controller

Comment: @AmitBera have you tested this?

Comment: no, I did not check it. Will be Check after 8hrs and reply you

Comment: Here is the cause of my problem CSS somewhere is adding the **disabled** selector to the form_key hidden input element. This means the form_key value is not submitted to the one step checkout controller causing the controller to return null. To test this, remove the disabled selector in your browser inspector.

Comment: See my answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176984/supee-9767-magento-ce-1-9-3-3-onestep-checkout-not-working-with-form-key-validat/177137#177137 dynamic checkout module code disables formkey input element.

Comment: @AmitBera FYI: some checkout plugins use AJAX to submit billing / shipping /etc. I just had to patch one. Easy way of doing it is putting <script> var formKey = "<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>"; </script> into head of theme. Then you can add form_key: formKey as a parameter to AJAX submission. Of course test the forms after to confirm submission of the new parameter and edit Controller to handle it like you mentioned in your post.

Comment: @FabianSchmengler unfortunately i receive the following error: 
"find: bad option
find: [-E] [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
./add-checkout-form-key.sh: syntax error at line 2: `|' unexpected". Do you have an advice how to fix it?

Comment: @DarkCowboy if you use a mac, please check the comments on the gist

Comment: I'm using Win7 and access my distant dev environment (ubuntu serveur) through ssh with putty.

Comment: Awesome - this worked for me. Replaced the line in the .js file to if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]' || elements[i].name == 'form_key') {

Answer (score 28):

Based on my first pass at review of the patch file...

- A new setting `admin/security/validate_formkey_checkout` has been added. When turned on, checkout forms are checked for presence of a form key. If the template files are overriden in the theme they'll need to be updated there. This setting seems to be off by default
- Symlinks seem to be disallowed by default (in `app/etc/config.xml`). Also, the ability to allow them seems to have been removed from the admin configuration. However, if your site previously explicitly enabled symlinks, the setting would be saved in the database, overriding this change.
- You need to clear both the cache AND the full page cache when applying this patch. The design exceptions are saved in a format the is incompatible with decoding. You'll see an error like this "Decoding failed: Syntax error" if you don't flush page cache.

Comment: You could also just go in with a hex editor and add it to the database yourself, but that may be a little much for most people

Comment: If some of you are using CDN, like cloudflare, make sure to purge cache. I tried going throigh checkout with CDN being active and it would no go past Payments page. The moment I purged cache and enabled Development mode, all went good.

Answer (score 16):

Below `base/default` file affected with this patch, if this files were in your theme then please make changes accordingly

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

in all above `phtml` files below form key line is added so please add this line in your respective phtml file.

```
 <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

For above issue @fabian created a script which will add form key even in your theme file

https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b

after applying security patch if you get error for form key you can apply this patch , for applying this patch process is same as security patch just

```
  sh filename.sh
```

and one `base/default` change in `Js` file

```
  skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

so if this `js` file is loading from your theme then do below steps

remove blow line

```
 if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]') {
```

and add below line instead of above

```
 if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]' || elements[i].name == 'form_key') {
```

**EDIT**

And if you are using any checkout extension which overrides below files then add form key line in checkout extension's phtml file.

**EDIT2 -- Issues**

1) Error at **saveBillingAction()** or getting form key null  Or Form Key issue : [Patch 9767 getting invalid Form Key](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176885/patch-9767-getting-invalid-form-key/176903#176903)

2) Hunk #1 FAILED at 225. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml   : [SUPEE-9767 - Hunk #1 FAILED at 225. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176886/supee-9767-hunk-1-failed-at-225-1-out-of-1-hunk-failed/176901#176901)

3) saving rejects to file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php.rej : [SUPEE-9767 ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176933/supee-9767-error-patch-cant-be-applied-reverted-successfully)

4) SUPEE-9767, modman and symlinks : [SUPEE-9767, modman and symlinks](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176952/supee-9767-modman-and-symlinks)

5) app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml Hunk #1 FAILED at 36. Hunk #2 FAILED at 54. 2 out of 2 hunks FAILED : [SUPEE-9767 Error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176981/supee-9767-error)

6) 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php : [Magento 1.9.2.2 SUPEE-9767 Patch ERROR](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176995/magento-1-9-2-2-supee-9767-patch-error)

7) onestep checkout error (again this is the form key issue) : [SUPEE-9767 Magento CE 1.9.3.3 Onestep Checkout not working with Form Key Validation On Checkout enabled](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176984/supee-9767-magento-ce-1-9-3-3-onestep-checkout-not-working-with-form-key-validat/177002#177002)

8) one step checkout customer registration issue : [SUPEE-9767 Patch/CE 1.9.3.3 - One Page Checkout - Customer Registration issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177035/supee-9767-patch-ce-1-9-3-3-one-page-checkout-customer-registration-issue)

9) app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php : [Magento SUPEE 9697 1.9.2.2 fails at Image.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177177/magento-supee-9697-1-9-2-2-fails-at-image-php)

Comment: Version 2 of the patch should be available soon. Bugs should be fixed.

Comment: @icon waiting for the v2

Answer (score 11):

## **Issue: Missing fixes in head-simple.phtml**

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/head-simple.phtml
```

need the same fixes as

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
```

Comment: For those looking, that fix is; https://github.com/nathandcornell/magento-patches/blob/f992e0b25e67252d8bd2f860e38c6541493f759d/CE1.9/PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-05-25-09-03-28.sh#L940

Answer (score 11):

Note that Symlinks have **always** been disabled by default on new Magento installations admin YES/NO config values default to 'NO'. The update now explicitly disables symlinks in config.xml and as an extra precaution also removes the template section from admin->developer which contained the configuration option.

This will not affect your current symlink settings, if you manually enabled symlinks prior to 1.9.3.2 they will stay enabled, although you cannot see the setting anymore in admin.

Users using [modman](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman) to manage Magento 1.x modules should ensure that they **do not disable symlinks** as this will disable the modman modules.

*Responsible admins* can enable the symlink admin section again by looking for the diff changes to the template section in app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml and adding the section to your system.xml at around line 600. Or double check symlinks are still enabled with

*n98-magerun.phar config:dump | grep symlink*

Here is the diff file for magento1933 and magento1932 to assist with identifying changes in the default theme which may affect your custom/extended themes.

diff -r magento1933 magento1932 > https://pastebin.com/ADzMBLhr

Comment: Why have they removed the Symlinks option?, is there now an exploit open to the public (outside of admin user) or is it just a risk if its on a shared environment?

Comment: this thread seems to answer my question : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176952/supee-9767-modman-and-symlinks

Comment: Symlinks are disabled for a reason. I suggest to copy instead of symlink: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177149/54863

Answer (score 11):

**Issue: Using php7 *sometimes* throws the following error:**

```
Decoding failed: Syntax error

#0 /______/app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php(179): Zend_Json::decode('')
#1 /______/app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php(215): Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Observer->_loadDesignExceptions()
#2 /______/app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php(125): Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Observer->_saveDesignException()
#3 /______/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Observer->cacheResponse(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 /______/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object({custom extensio}_Model_Rewrite_PageCache_Observer), 'cacheResponse', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 /______/app/Mage.php(456): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_fron...', Array)
#6 /______/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(182): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_fron...', Array)
#7 /______/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /______/app/Mage.php(691): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /______/index.php(105): Mage::run('brandfield_nl', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Its pretty sure that Zend version has to do something with it. A fast fix is this but is for sure not correct:

-> app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php:244 replace it with:

```
    if ($cachedSslOffloaderHeader !== false) {
        $cachedSslOffloaderHeader = trim(@Zend_Json::decode($cachedSslOffloaderHeader));
    }
```

-> and app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php:177 with:

```
    if ($exceptions !== false) {
        $exceptions = Zend_Json::decode($exceptions);
    }
```

Of course create an addon to rewrite this. But I am sure there is something better to be done here.

**UPDATE (Better solution)**

-> Go to: lib/Zend/Json.php and after the line 76 add this:

```
    if ((float)phpversion() >= 7.0
        && empty($encodedValue)
    ) {
        return null;
    }
```

Create your extension to override it and dont edit the core file.

Comment: Cache was cleared completely. This is not the same issue.

Comment: We hit this same issue - reverting app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php removed the problem, but obviously that is not the correct fix, just prevention


`a:5:{i:0;s:29:"Decoding failed: Syntax error";i:1;s:1376:"#0 app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php(177): Zend_Json::decode('a:0:{}')`

Answer (score 11):

### Issue: Dynamic code or css disables form key input element at checkout

An issue I have seen is where **dynamic code** (paypal plus) in the one page checkout process overwrites the *fieldset* element in the one step payment method form html - deleting or disabling  (with css) the hidden form_key element.

The fix is to ensure the **formkey** element is not being **disabled** by any dynamic code or css. Moving the formkey code outside of the *fieldset* element may also help

```
<form>
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

You can easily confirm if the form_key is being detected and sent to the one page controller by inspecting the ajax network requests in your browser as you move through the checkout methods, each method should include the form key in the ajax form data, if the form key is not there but the Magento source code has been patched check for external code affecting the form key element, i.e. css or dynamic client side changes.

[image]

Comment: This bit of fix didn't seem to work for me with EE. 
I found that the file `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/giftcardaccount/onepage/payment/scripts.phtml`  needed to be updated as well:

Lines 35-38 need to be updated to include `|| elements[i].name == 'form_key'` along with the other selectors to keep the form_key form field being disabled.

Comment: Thanks g-man1066! That was exactly the problem I was having.

Answer (score 10):

**ISSUE:** **Customer Registration Fails when using generic Magento 5-step checkout.**

**This issue is only presented when we ENABLE form key authentication.** Version used: 1.7.0.2, but looks like someone has posted that same issue occurs on 1.9.3 version too.
[SUPEE-9767 Patch/CE 1.9.3.3 - One Page Checkout - Customer Registration issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177035/supee-9767-patch-ce-1-9-3-3-one-page-checkout-customer-registration-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1)

When Go to checkout, we are presented with 2 options: CHECKOUT AS A GUEST OR REGISTER
Once click "Register", and fill-out the form along with password, you proceed throguh all steps and complete the order. Order gets placed, BUT customer never gets registered in magento. It looks like Guest placed order.

When I went back and **Disabled** form key authentication, and tried placing order while registering as a customer, it got placed without any problems and the customer got registered in the backend.

Comment: Here's a more detailed post about this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177035/supee-9767-patch-ce-1-9-3-3-one-page-checkout-customer-registration-issue

Answer (score 9):

### UPDATE 13/07/2017 [ THE ISSUE IS FIXED ]

Magento team has released [SUPEE-9767 V2](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2034) in this version of the patch the problem with transparent gif's and png's is fixed.

You should revert all changes to the file that was discussed in this thread. Then revert the applied V1 patch and finally apply the new version V2.

---

### PRE - SUPEE-9767 V2

#### Please don't use the code discussed bellow instead apply V2 of the patch the problem discussed bellow is already fixed in this version

If somebody experience problem with transparent png's that when uploaded from the admin panel the background becomes black. (On the products) is in relation to the Image Upload callback introduced in:

`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php`

In the moment I am not sure what exactly is causing this behaviour but I am trying to figure it out I can confirm that when the callback is removed the strange behaviour is going away.

[image]

### UPDATE

Ok, I found the function that is also updated from SUPEE-9767 this is actually breaking the transparency in the png's a copy of the original image is created without transparency.

```
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
@@ -87,10 +87,33 @@ public function setAllowedImageTypes(array $imageFileExtensions = array())
      */
     public function validate($filePath)
     {
-        $fileInfo = getimagesize($filePath);
-        if (is_array($fileInfo) and isset($fileInfo[2])) {
-            if ($this->isImageType($fileInfo[2])) {
-                return null;
+        list($imageWidth, $imageHeight, $fileType) = getimagesize($filePath);
+        if ($fileType) {
+            if ($this->isImageType($fileType)) {
+                //replace tmp image with re-sampled copy to exclude images with malicious data
+                $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filePath));
+                if ($image !== false) {
+                    $img = imagecreatetruecolor($imageWidth, $imageHeight);
+                    imagecopyresampled($img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);
+                    switch ($fileType) {
+                        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
+                            imagegif($img, $filePath);
+                            break;
+                        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
+                            imagejpeg($img, $filePath, 100);
+                            break;
+                        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
+                            imagepng($img, $filePath);
+                            break;
+                        default:
+                            return;
+                    }
+                    imagedestroy($img);
+                    imagedestroy($image);
+                    return null;
+                } else {
+                    throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid image.'));
+                }
             }
         }
         throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid MIME type.'));
```

### UPDATE

Here is updated version of the function to preserve the png transparency

```
  imagealphablending($img, false);
  imagesavealpha($img, true);
```

these two lines need to be added to the patch.
Update the function in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php`

```
/**
 * Validation callback for checking is file is image
 *
 * @param  string $filePath Path to temporary uploaded file
 * @return null
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 */
public function validate($filePath)
{
    list($imageWidth, $imageHeight, $fileType) = getimagesize($filePath);
    if ($fileType) {
        if ($this->isImageType($fileType)) {
            //replace tmp image with re-sampled copy to exclude images with malicious data
            $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filePath));
            if ($image !== false) {
                $img = imagecreatetruecolor($imageWidth, $imageHeight);
                imagealphablending($img, false);
                imagesavealpha($img, true);  
                imagecopyresampled($img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);
                switch ($fileType) {
                    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                        imagegif($img, $filePath);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                        imagejpeg($img, $filePath, 100);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                        imagepng($img, $filePath);
                        break;
                    default:
                        return;
                }
                imagedestroy($img);
                imagedestroy($image);
                return null;
            } else {
                throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid image.'));
            }
        }
    }
    throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid MIME type.'));
}
```

### UPDATE 23/06/17

This updated version of the function fixes the PNG and the GIF transparency.

```
    /**
 * Validation callback for checking is file is image
 *
 * @param  string $filePath Path to temporary uploaded file
 * @return null
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 */
public function validate($filePath)
{
    list($imageWidth, $imageHeight, $fileType) = getimagesize($filePath);
    if ($fileType) {
        if ($this->isImageType($fileType)) {
            //replace tmp image with re-sampled copy to exclude images with malicious data
            $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filePath));
            if ($image !== false) {
                $img = imagecreatetruecolor($imageWidth, $imageHeight);
                switch ($fileType) {
                    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                        imagecolortransparent($img, imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127));
                        imagealphablending($img, false);
                        imagesavealpha($img, true);
                        imagecopyresampled($img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);
                        imagegif($img, $filePath);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                        imagecopyresampled($img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);
                        imagejpeg($img, $filePath, 100);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                        imagealphablending($img, false);
                        imagesavealpha($img, true);  
                        imagecopyresampled($img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);
                        imagepng($img, $filePath);
                        break;
                    default:
                        return;
                }
                imagedestroy($img);
                imagedestroy($image);
                return null;
            } else {
                throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid image.'));
            }
        }
    }
    throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid MIME type.'));
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem in a Magento 1.7 installation. Thanks!

Comment: No problem Tjitse just make a note of this change in case the Magento team don't fix the patch you will have to revert it when you doing the next patch. I have submitted the problem to the community at bugcrowd.com hope they will introduce patch fix soon.

Comment: this does fix it for pngs, but not for transparent gif files. gif files need slightly different handling using imagecolortransparent

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out alternize see the updated function that fixes the gif transparency also.

Answer (score 8):

## Issue: Allow symlink notification not shown to admins

The symlink notification will not be shown in the admin notification area as it is not included in the `<block type="core/text_list" name="notifications" as="notifications">`

The patch for both CE and EE below:

```
--- app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
+++ app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
@@ -119,7 +119,8 @@ Default layout, loads most of the pages
<block type="adminhtml/cache_notifications" name="cache_notifications" template="system/cache/notifications.phtml"></block>
<block type="adminhtml/notification_survey" name="notification_survey" template="notification/survey.phtml"/>
<block type="adminhtml/notification_security" name="notification_security" as="notification_security" template="notification/security.phtml"></block>
-            </block>
+                <block type="adminhtml/checkout_formkey" name="checkout_formkey" as="checkout_formkey" template="notification/formkey.phtml"/></block>
+                <block type="adminhtml/notification_symlink" name="notification_symlink" template="notification/symlink.phtml"/>
<block type="adminhtml/widget_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"></block>
<!--<update handle="formkey"/> this won't work, see the try/catch and a jammed exception in Mage_Core_Model_Layout::createBlock() -->
```

The issue is `</block>` is at the end of `checkout_formkey` (which is self-terminating) and therefore closes the parent `notifications`. This causes the `notification_symlink` to not be included in the `core/text_list` and not be rendered.

Comment: This is not really an issue, the notification has been removed because symlinks have been explicitly disabled and the symlink config section removed. It's not possible to manually change the symlink value in admin  in v1933 so therefore showing an admin notification is rather pointless. The issue will be for new 1933 installations where users who require symlinks i.e. for modman can no longer manually enable it. One could infer that Magento doesn't expect any new 1.x installations...

Comment: I disagree, this patch does not explicitly disable the config if it is already set - it only disables it if it is not already set.  Therefore if an instance has dev/template/allow_symlink set to yes in the DB/local.xml prior to this patch and they apply the patch they SHOULD receive the warning that symlinks are allowed as they are potentially vulnerable.

Comment: I see your point, and you are correct. But for a normal user what would they then do - it's impossible to manually disable it from admin as the config option has been removed. It's a bit of a catch 22 situation...

Answer (score 8):

Little tip for #patchday; after copying 1.9.3.3 over your install, run `git diff -w --stat | grep -v " 2 +" | grep -v "   0"` to quickly see bigger changes in files.

Answer (score 8):

**Issue: EE shipping template not patched**

I patched an EE 1.13.1.0 install, and the enterprise shipping template (`app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml`) did not have the formkey added, but the billing and payment templates did.

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml` *was* patched.

Comment: I also needed (for EE 1.14.2)  to add the form_key  to 
`/app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template...`  
`.../checkout/cart/coupon.phtml`, `.../giftcardaccount/cart/block.phtml`
`.../giftcardaccount/cart/check.phtml`

Answer (score 5):

There is an issue with Magento EE versions that are patched with SUPEE-9767 (so not with upgrades to 1.14.3.3). The form key on that page will be cached. So when I flush my cache and then go to a product page and make sure the page is completely cached (refresh a couple of times), I should be able to add that product to my cart.

Now, when I open a different browser (or incognito mode), open the same page and try to add the product to the cart again. The product will not be added to cart, because of the form key. Now when you flush the cache again, the product can be added to the cart again.

Thanks to [Jasper Zeinstra](https://commercehero.io/jasperzeinstra)

Answer (score 4):

For developers using Magento Composer Intaller, you can change the deployment strategy to Copy instead of Symlink. You can also configure to append the module files to your .gitignore, so your repository will stay clean.

https://github.com/Cotya/magento-composer-installer/blob/master/doc/Deploy.md#deploy-per-copy-instead-of-symlink

`{
    "extra":{
        "magento-root-dir": "htdocs/",
        "magento-deploystrategy": "copy",
        "auto-append-gitignore": true
    }
}`

Comment: We found out that with copy `"magento-force": true,` becomes important

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue on EE 1.14.2.2 with FPC enabled and this patch applied.

Intermittently users could not add to cart.

Explanation and fix here:
[SUPEE-9767 issue : Add to cart issue, Enterprise Full Page Cache](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177942/supee-9767-issue-add-to-cart-issue-enterprise-full-page-cache)

Answer (score 3):

Issue: Patch was working on vanilla Magento 1.7.0.0 [edited]

During the testing of our patch script we discovered a problem in the patch for Magento 1.7.0.0. Don't know if anybody still uses it, but anyhow it is a problem in SUPEE-9767. We used a vanilla install and we installed all previous patches first.

Patch file used: `PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2017-05-25-09-31-32.sh`
The patch file **does** work for Magento 1.7.0.1 and 1.7.0.2

Summary of problems:

```
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
...
can't find file to patch at input line 377
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|index 7f7b9d0..cbbcbb1 100644
|--- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
...
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 502.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
...
```

For the record, this on on the 1.7.0.0 we tried the patch on:

```
$ grep SUPEE app/etc/applied.patches.list
2017-06-01 12:59:49 UTC | SUPEE-2677 | EE_1.13.0.2 | v2 | d20e6763cd0df70c4ac6e418c9775a1ff0f2618f | Tue Jan 14 17:49:25 2014 +0200 | v1.13.0.2..HEAD
2017-06-01 12:59:49 UTC | SUPEE-2629 | EE_1.12.0.0 | v1 | 5de775cf535e137b0b099d8066bd5b3a81f7ec4c | Wed Dec 11 16:50:40 2013 +0200 | v1.12.0.0..HEAD
-e 2017-06-01 12:59:49 UTC | SUPEE-1049 | EE-1.12.0.2 | v1 | 6d06f286f461562fa6d6573349f1491f7bf89859 | Wed Feb 13 17:46:13 2013 -0800 | v1.12.0.2..HEAD
2017-06-01 12:59:49 UTC | SUPEE-1868-1-12-0-2 | EE_1.12.0.2 | v1 | 2148b1b6be28a9bad0bec9a4aecc63ed318dd201 | Fri Jul 26 13:20:27 2013 -0700 | v1.12.0.2..HEAD
2017-06-01 12:59:49 UTC | SUPEE-4334-v1.11.1.0 | EE_1.11.1.0 | v1 | 40f5a2e4db9ca53dc6a8e62eb0c728fd63b1157e | Wed Sep 10 10:42:31 2014 -0700 | ef80f7bff749c941b4d1736cc2b502888e7540c9
2017-06-01 12:59:49 UTC | SUPEE-5345 | EE_1.12.0.2 | v1 | 2d36f61cf684ed26286b6d10307fcb99dd47ff02 | Thu Feb 5 19:39:01 2015 +0200 | v1.12.0.2..HEAD
2017-06-01 12:59:49 UTC | SUPEE-5994 | CE_1.6.0.0 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1.patch
2017-06-01 12:59:49 UTC | SUPEE-6237 | EE_1.14.2.0 | v1 | 8b216c42e2e5d2cb5d8e500fcb6690abede9df52 | Fri Jun 12 13:39:59 2015 +0300 | v1.14.2.0..HEAD
2017-06-01 12:59:49 UTC | SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.7.0.2 | v1 | 84749c91e14543e1f96af30e86efdf29f4562c98 | Tue Jun 23 09:48:07 2015 +0300 | c6e6cee8eb..84749c91e1
2017-06-01 12:59:49 UTC | SUPEE-6482 | CE_1.8.0.0 | v1 |  | Tue Jul 14 14:17:04 2015 +0300 |
2017-06-01 12:59:49 UTC | SUPEE-6788 | CE_1.7.0.1 | v1 | 04d237d56b116989e46839c41691585d927f99db | Fri Oct 23 13:52:50 2015 +0300 | f69136a
2017-06-01 12:59:49 UTC | SUPEE-7616 | CE_1.7.0.2-CE_1.4.2.0 | v1 | a16c51e3679c3f19de6c3207b7a42daa7f9227fc | Fri Dec 18 12:42:03 2015 +0200 | 3617437b6da11be812fcca85f4e6ecbd8b8dc94c..a16c51e3679c3f19de6c3207b7a42daa7f9227fc
2017-06-01 12:59:50 UTC | SUPEE-8788 | CE_1.7.0.0 | v2 | 6b5ef4fc5b09af74d0fd401440948d0a54dd203d | Fri Oct 14 19:27:22 2016 +0300 | 84fa3dd598466fa5c482965a3f8e5395af33bf9d
2017-06-01 12:59:50 UTC | SUPEE-8967 | EE_1.13.1.0 | v1 | 1fa53e9533f6f3a16f24d9b64dabef0ab7f965d7 | Thu Aug 18 16:32:48 2016 +0300 | 97d160644..1fa53e9533
2017-06-01 12:59:50 UTC | SUPEE-9652 | EE_1.14.3.1 | v1 | 4038f0785d828794083f53f10c01aaa6af403523 | Tue Jan 24 15:03:12 2017 +0200 | 9586981e6ca8b255014b242d50b68b88525b0754..4038f0785d828794083f53f10c01aaa6af403523
```

Comment: If you are missing that file, you most likely have not applied security patch SUPEE-7405.

Comment: @RyanHoerr you are right, SUPEE-7405 was skipped because the official file `PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2016-01-20-04-58-44.sh` does not work for 1.7.0.0. I created a fixed version of the file. If anyone needs it, send me a message.

Answer (score 3):

I just had to revert this patch due to some strange behavior. For whatever reason, certain users could not add certain items to their cart.

I'm assuming it has something to do with old quotes colliding with the current quote for that customer. I verified this issue by logging in as the user to make sure it wasn't just a 1D10T.

It's been an issue since I took that patch life last Friday. **We are using 1.14.2.4**. We are heavily modified so it might work fine for other users. Just a warning!

Comment: That is correct, patch does break add to cart action for EE version of the Magento. Basically, the issue occurs due to PageCache module having one version of form_key generation logic, while the session has its own. When FPC has the cached version of the requested page, but needs to regenerate minicart, session is triggered which regenerates form_key at the same time FPC save is called which generates its own form_key. At that point session value of form_key differs from one stored in customer cookie (used in FPC processor) so you are getting invalid key on add to cart controller.

Comment: I'm also encountering this issue. I'll let you know if I find a fix.

Comment: I resolved this issue, explanation here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177942/supee-9767-issue-add-to-cart-issue-enterprise-full-page-cache

Comment: Does anyone know if this is resolved in SUPEE-9767 v2?

Answer (score 3):

**Issue:** ***Infinite redirect loop on 1.6.0.0***

**Quick Fix**

Find the below lines inside the method ***protected function _checkBaseUrl($request)*** in the file ***app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php***

```
 if (isset($uri['scheme']) && $uri['scheme'] != $request->getScheme()
        || isset($uri['host']) && $uri['host'] != $request->getHttpHost()
        || isset($uri['path']) && strpos($requestUri, $uri['path']) === false
 ) {
```

Change these lines to

```
 if (isset($uri['host']) && $uri['host'] != $request->getHttpHost()
            || isset($uri['path']) && strpos($requestUri, $uri['path']) === false
 ) {
```

After that save the file (commit to your REPO), clear the cache (remove everything inside var/cache folder) and reload your store front. You should find the site loads without anymore 302 redirect issues after applying the SUPEE 9767 Patch.

**Root Cause**

The difference in SCHEME value between the actual Request and the URI after redirection. Eg: The actual request returns the scheme HTTP but the scheme in the URI can be HTTPS.

**Possible Underlying Reasons**

1. You may most likely have a redirect rule in .htaccess file to redirect all the http requests to https. The user requests http://yourdomain.com and you may have changed the scheme and redirected him to https://yourdomain instead of http://yourdomain.com which he had actually requested.
2. Both the base secure and unsecure URLs begin with https

Answer (score 3):

The CONFIRMED BUG *"Customer registration fails at checkout"* occurred a bit different on my side.

If the customer choose register in checkout then its password is not correctly stored. The customer is created correctly just that the password is not stored. I detected this by the fact that the password was not shown in welcome email.
People can't login because of this too.

Bugfix linked in [SUPEE-9767 Patch/CE 1.9.3.3 - One Page Checkout - Customer Registration issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177035/supee-9767-patch-ce-1-9-3-3-one-page-checkout-customer-registration-issue/177125#177125) has done the job for me too.

Answer (score 3):

Can anyone tell me what the f... is this s... for in supee-9767?

[image]

Comment: The jQuery 1.10.2 version is considered vulnerable, and flagged by some PCI scanners. The 1.12 version is not.

Comment: @Detzler StackExchange isn't a forum. If you want to ask a question, you should post one, not an answer to a question.

Comment: Ryan Hoerr asked about any issues brought by the patch. So I told him a possible breaking change as you see at the screenshot. I can not explain the reason for this change. So I sub asked. So what's your problem?

Answer (score 3):

The patch doesn't work even for a vanilla Magento 1.7.0.2.

```
martins@martinsmac.local:/var/www/magento1702-original$ ./PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2017-05-25-09-31-32.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 109 (offset -29 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 293 (offset -34 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 313 (offset -34 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 363 (offset -34 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 392 (offset -34 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 431 (offset -34 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 141 (offset -7 lines).
can't find file to patch at input line 377
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|index 7f7b9d0..cbbcbb1 100644
|--- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 502.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/etc/config.xml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
patching file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 400 (offset -5 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 923 (offset -5 lines).
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
Hunk #2 succeeded at 235 with fuzz 2 (offset -13 lines).
patching file js/varien/payment.js
patching file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

even after applying older patches manually.

```
$ grep '|' app/etc/applied.patches.list
2017-06-19 04:01:42 UTC | SUPEE-2677 | EE_1.13.0.2 | v2 | d20e6763cd0df70c4ac6e418c9775a1ff0f2618f | Tue Jan 14 17:49:25 2014 +0200 | v1.13.0.2..HEAD
2017-06-19 04:03:26 UTC | SUPEE-2629 | EE_1.12.0.0 | v1 | 5de775cf535e137b0b099d8066bd5b3a81f7ec4c | Wed Dec 11 16:50:40 2013 +0200 | v1.12.0.0..HEAD
2017-06-19 04:04:12 UTC | SUPEE-1049 | EE_1.12.0.2 | v1 | 5cd884653325315804056d4c591572385b3c1d03 | Thu Mar 20 16:33:19 2014 +0200 | v1.12.0.2..HEAD
2017-06-19 04:05:01 UTC | SUPEE-1868-1-12-0-2 | EE_1.12.0.2 | v1 | 2148b1b6be28a9bad0bec9a4aecc63ed318dd201 | Fri Jul 26 13:20:27 2013 -0700 | v1.12.0.2..HEAD
2017-06-19 04:06:38 UTC | SUPEE-4334-v1.11.1.0 | EE_1.11.1.0 | v1 | 40f5a2e4db9ca53dc6a8e62eb0c728fd63b1157e | Wed Sep 10 10:42:31 2014 -0700 | ef80f7bff749c941b4d1736cc2b502888e7540c9
2017-06-19 04:07:10 UTC | SUPEE-1533 | EE_1.12 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-1533_EE_1.12_v1.patch
2017-06-19 04:08:41 UTC | SUPEE-5345 | EE_1.12.0.2 | v1 | 2d36f61cf684ed26286b6d10307fcb99dd47ff02 | Thu Feb 5 19:39:01 2015 +0200 | v1.12.0.2..HEAD
2017-06-19 04:09:29 UTC | SUPEE-5994 | CE_1.6.0.0 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1.patch
2017-06-19 04:10:00 UTC | SUPEE-6237 | EE_1.14.2.0 | v1 | 8b216c42e2e5d2cb5d8e500fcb6690abede9df52 | Fri Jun 12 13:39:59 2015 +0300 | v1.14.2.0..HEAD
2017-06-19 04:11:22 UTC | SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.7.0.2 | v1 | 84749c91e14543e1f96af30e86efdf29f4562c98 | Tue Jun 23 09:48:07 2015 +0300 | c6e6cee8eb..84749c91e1
2017-06-19 04:11:50 UTC | SUPEE-6482 | CE_1.8.0.0 | v1 |  | Tue Jul 14 14:17:04 2015 +0300 |
2017-06-19 04:12:12 UTC | SUPEE-7616 | CE_1.7.0.2-CE_1.4.2.0 | v1 | a16c51e3679c3f19de6c3207b7a42daa7f9227fc | Fri Dec 18 12:42:03 2015 +0200 | 3617437b6da11be812fcca85f4e6ecbd8b8dc94c..a16c51e3679c3f19de6c3207b7a42daa7f9227fc
2017-06-19 04:14:30 UTC | SUPEE-8167 | EE_1.12.0.2 | v1 | b1be28f9cd8c2ecba2aa403e59ad9e3d2855eb95 | Thu May 4 13:52:13 2017 +0300 | 8d12ea6fe564b6dc9ed1affb6de990f81aca3796..HEAD
2017-06-19 04:16:21 UTC | SUPEE-8967 | EE_1.13.1.0 | v1 | 1fa53e9533f6f3a16f24d9b64dabef0ab7f965d7 | Thu Aug 18 16:32:48 2016 +0300 | 97d160644..1fa53e9533
2017-06-19 04:16:44 UTC | SUPEE-9652 | EE_1.14.3.1 | v1 | 4038f0785d828794083f53f10c01aaa6af403523 | Tue Jan 24 15:03:12 2017 +0200 | 9586981e6ca8b255014b242d50b68b88525b0754..4038f0785d828794083f53f10c01aaa6af403523
2017-06-19 04:19:35 UTC | SUPEE-6788 | CE_1.7.0.2 | v1 | 0398c4b951d9a0f64495e7b8b3b8ca480952dd70 | Fri Oct 23 13:50:23 2015 +0300 | cfc252b
```

**The solution/problem I found** is that some of the changes in the patch for 1.7.0.2 is for files that doesn't exist before 1.9.2.3. So I copied the following files from a brand new 1.9.2.3 installation *before* running the patch script:

- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
- app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php

Comment: The patch assumes all other security patches have already been applied. The files you are talking about were added/changed by previous patches. You're missing at least SUPEE-7405.

Comment: Hi Ryan,
In fact I tried to apply 7405 as well, but didn't work either... 
$ ./PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.7.0.2_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-22-52\ \(1\).sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
(..)Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 121.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file (..)Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php.rej
patching file (..)/Core/Model/Config.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1642.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file 
(..) Config.php.rej
patching file (..)/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 509....

Comment: @RicardoMartins how can i solve this error : patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv Hunk #2 FAILED at 36. 1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv.rej

 ?

Answer (score 1):

Jut an addition to https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176930/46249

> Note that Symlinks have always been disabled by default on new Magento
>   installations admin YES/NO config values default to 'NO'. The update
>   now explicitly disables symlinks in config.xml and as an extra
>   precaution also removes the template section from admin->developer
>   which contained the configuration option.
>
> **This will not affect your current symlink settings, if you manually
>   enabled symlinks prior to 1.9.3.2 they will stay enabled, although you
>   cannot see the setting anymore in admin.**

---

The bold text isn't correct. If updating to **1.9.3.4 (SUPEE-9767 V2)** or newer current settings will be deleted:

```
# app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.6-1.6.0.7.php
$connection->delete(
    $this->getTable('core_config_data'),
    $connection->prepareSqlCondition('path', array(
        'like' => 'dev/template/allow_symlink'
    ))
);
```

> Responsible admins can enable the symlink admin section again by
>   looking for the diff changes to the template section in
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml and adding the section to your
>   system.xml at around line 600. Or double check symlinks are still
>   enabled with

Just make config option visible again does no solve the problem. The option shows up, but you're not able to change config since newly introduced backend model prevents saving the value. See:

```
# app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
<backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_symlink</backend_model>
```

and

```
# Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Symlink
public function save()
{
    return $this;
}
```

So you have to remove or override this backend model, see [How to enable symlinks after SUPEE-9767 V2 install?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184184/how-to-enable-symlinks-after-supee-9767-v2-install/184185#184185)