# Patch 9767 getting invalid Form Key

Tags: magento-1, security, patches, supee-9767

I just patched my dev machine with Security Patch 9767. And enabled form key on checkout from backend. Also added the form key to my custom theme. But When I tested the checkout process it freeze on billing step. I tried to log the **`saveBillingAction()`** on `OnePageController.php` the result is **0**

```
Mage::log( ((int) $this->_validateFormKey() ) , null , 'custom.log' );
```

Any help are much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

open your below file and add form key into it

```
 app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

and add below form key code into it

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

**Solution 2**

If you are not able to do this then download below patch

https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b

and apply this patch as you applied security patch and this patch will add that form key even in your custom theme's phtml file

Answer (score 3):

```
Open following file and add following code just before </form>

<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>

/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
```

All the checkout steps needs form key after installing security patch 9767 when Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout set to Yes under admin configuration.