# Magento 2.2.2 Security Patch Issue

Tags: magento2, security, bug

I have download PRODSECBUG-2233 from magento official site

> patch -p1 < PRODSECBUG-2233-2.2.x-2019-07-26-08-35-48.patch

**When i try to use this command, it's not working and show me this errors.**

```
can't find file to patch at input line 8
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: app/code/Magento/Sales/Helper/Admin.php
|IDEA additional info:
|Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
|<+>UTF-8
|===================================================================
|--- app/code/Magento/Sales/Helper/Admin.php    (revision d46f8efde7d6e7c40859e833f462c30edc101476)
|+++ app/code/Magento/Sales/Helper/Admin.php    (revision 102b397919b1c82aa13118abb5345ad81c626370)
```

How can i solve this ? Thanks

Magento 2.2.2 CE CentOS Server

Comment: Which directory are you running the patch command?

Comment: in public_html (root folder)

Comment: Did you install Magento with composer?

Comment: Check here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/254815/magento-2-2-4-composer-patch-failed-1-out-of-1-hunk-ignored/254816#254816

Comment: I used fullpackage from template monsters. I know was a bad idea, but but I was still learning.

Comment: Ok, which of the following folders exist in your set up: app/code/Magento/ folder or vendor/magento/?

Comment: Both. But in app/code/magento was only translation /i18n/. In vendor/magento/ there are all modules.

Comment: Ok then modify the patch as defined on that answer I shared above and it should be ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97958/discussion-between-muhammedv-and-kernelpanic).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2.2.4 Composer Patch Failed: "1 out of 1 hunk ignored"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/254815/magento-2-2-4-composer-patch-failed-1-out-of-1-hunk-ignored)