# Magento 2.2.5 Security Patch Issue

Tags: patches, magento-2.2.5

Was there any solution to this? - [Magento 2.2.2 Security Patch Issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286736/magento-2-2-2-security-patch-issue)

I have the same issue with PRODSECBUG-2233 on Magento 2.2.5 - Installed via composer and using composer version of patch.

When I install it says it can't find:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Helper/Admin.php
vendor/magento/module-sales/Test/Unit/Helper/AdminTest.php
```

Files are there in those directories. When I specify the files I get:

```
File to patch: vendor/magento/module-sales/Helper/Admin.php
patching file vendor/magento/module-sales/Helper/Admin.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 6.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 27 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 158.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 195.
3 out of 4 hunks FAILED

File to patch: vendor/magento/module-sales/Test/Unit/Helper/AdminTest.php
patching file vendor/magento/module-sales/Test/Unit/Helper/AdminTest.php
Hunk #2 succeeded at 324 (offset -6 lines).
```

The line ends on the patch and Admin.php match and Admin.php has not been altered from the original file in the 2.2.5 release. All other security patches have been applied so don't believe it's a missing patch that has previously altered admin.php unless someone can point me in the direction of a patch that's required?

I've been trying to match up the hunks to work out if it doesn't have enough context to know where to insert the code but I get a bit lost with how it's specified.

Patch hunk 1:

```
    @@ -6,6 +6,8 @@

 namespace Magento\Sales\Helper;

+use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
+
 /**
  * Sales admin helper.
  */
```

And admin.php line 6 to 11 as specified:

```
namespace Magento\Sales\Helper;

class Admin extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Config
```

I'm guessing its the `class Admin extends` throwing it off?

There's meant to be 3 lines of context above and below right? if so then neither the top or the bottom of the hunk matches the original file so is this a bugged patch or am I going way of base?

Answer (score 0):

did you solve this issue ? I have 2.2.6 Magento Composer version that I cannot patch and it is very alarming.
Best regards
JG