# SUPEE-9767 ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully

Tags: security, patches, magento-ee, supee-9767

Trying to apply newly released patch on our Magento EE 1.14.3.2 but getting the following error.

```
bash PATCH_SUPEE-9767_EE_1.14.3.2_v1-2017-05-22-07-20-39.sh 
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/community/OnTap/Merchandiser/Model/Resource/Merchandiser.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/CatalogEvent/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/EventController.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftWrapping/Model/Wrapping.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/Model/Config.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/Model/Invitation.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Helper/Form/Key.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 135 with fuzz 2 (offset 59 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #6 FAILED at 1093.
Hunk #7 FAILED at 1214.
2 out of 7 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/merchandiser.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/customerbalance/checkout/onepage/payment/additional.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/giftcardaccount/multishipping/payment.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/giftcardaccount/onepage/payment/scripts.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/invitation/form.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/layout/page.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/customerbalance/checkout/onepage/payment/additional.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/giftcardaccount/multishipping/payment.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/giftcardaccount/onepage/payment/scripts.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/invitation/form.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/reward/checkout/onepage/payment/additional.phtml
patching file app/etc/config.xml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Enterprise_Invitation.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
patching file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
patching file js/varien/payment.js
patching file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
patching file skin/frontend/enterprise/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue has been resolved and the patch is applied with the following method.

There are two reasons you might experience issues with the patch. If you have previously applied patch PATCH_SUPEE-9805_EE_1.14.3.2_v1.sh, the fixed from this patch is included in the security patch.

If you have PATCH_SUPEE-9805_EE_1.14.3.2_v1.sh applied you should revert it using

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-9805_EE_1.14.3.2_v1.sh -R
```

prior to applying SUPEE-9767.

Another reason could be, the line ending of the files are in the incorrect format. This most commonly happens if the patch file is saved on a Windows machine, then uploaded to a Linux-based server.

To resolve this issue, please run the following command:

```
dos2unix PATCH_SUPEE-9767_EE_1.14.3.2_v1-2017-05-22-07-20-39.sh
```

The dos2unix utility may not be installed on your server

To install dos2unix on CentOS, Fedora or RHEL use:

```
$ sudo yum install dos2unix
```

To install dos2unix on Ubuntu or Debian use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tofrodos
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/fromdos /usr/bin/dos2unix
```

---

After above run the patch installation process.

Comment: nice explanation ...

Comment: I still have the issue after installing dos2unix :(

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure About this problem:

This could be because of following two problems:

1. You have modified that file manually for your purpose : in that case revert that file from original.
2. That file has wrong permissions : In this case set 644 default permission to this file.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason could be that you [modified the core file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VivBI.jpg) `app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php`

To fix that:

- Backup this file
- Download the original file of your Magento version
- Apply the patch
- Compare your backup with the new file
- Copy the new file under `app/code/local/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php`
- Apply your custom changes to this new file

Comment: This is my post : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/204446/57334.    after i deleted Mage_Adminhtml.csv from my root folder and replaced by core Mage_Adminhtml.csv. still not working