# PATCH_SUPEE-10266 Installation Error - Mage_Adminhtml.csv?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, patches, supee-10266

How can i solve,

```
    patching file app/design/install/default/default/template/install/create_admin.p                                                                            html

    patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv

can't find file to patch at input line 720
```

Patch File:

> 720th Line :

```
  '<input class="input-text" type="text" name="product[options][{{option_id}}][image_size_y]" value="{{image_size_y}}">' +
```

How can i solve the error?

Comment: compare file with default magento

Comment: @VaibhavAhalpara after i deleted Mage_Adminhtml.csv from my root folder and replaced by core Mage_Adminhtml.csv. still not working

Comment: @RamaChandranM sorry, my mistake your post getting down,

Comment: https://www.diffnow.com/?report=qh5mo clip 2

Comment: Bro, i am replaced my root Mage_Adminhtml.csv by core Mage_Adminhtml.csv. still getting error.

Comment: @RamaChandranM   Is anything i can do?

Comment: Are you applied 9767 v2 ? what exact version magento you are using?

Comment: could you pls help me 9767 v2 error https://justpaste.it/1e8te

Comment: @RamaChandranM nope, 9767 v1 not successfully revert

Comment: @RamaChandranM let me explain clearly, as you know if apply patch 9767 v2, first revert patch 9767 v1, i am getting error if i apply patch 9767 v1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69798/discussion-between-zus-and-rama-chandran-m).

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your csv `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv`

9767v2 security patch changes not applied in your csv file. 
I have provided the file. please check it and apply.

Hope it will helpful for you. Thanks

Comment: Actually i deleted downloader file, so i removed these lines from Patch https://snag.gy/4R2Y1a.jpg, aftre run the patch i am getting above error?

Comment: after i deleted Mage_Adminhtml.csv from my root folder and replaced by core Mage_Adminhtml.csv. still not working

Comment: @RamaChandranM, NO DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THIS COMMENT AND ANSWER

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara Actually my question completely changed, so that he edit his answer.

Comment: @RamaChandranM after i deleted Mage_Adminhtml.csv from my root folder and replaced by core Mage_Adminhtml.csv. still not working

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps.

(1) First revert the patch if applied.

(2) Check your current magento version and download same fresh version.

(3) Just put `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv` file from downloded version

(4) Now apply patch again .

Error will be resolved.
Dont forget to clear cache.

Comment: I did same what you told, not working.

Comment: what is mean .rej after Mage_Adminhtml.csv like Mage_Adminhtml.csv.rej

Comment: @zus ok then issue is you need to apply 9767 patch then apply this patch.

Comment: @zus it means someone modified that file either patch or manually .

Comment: bro, i already updated 9767 patch

Comment: @zus ok then download zip file of 9767 patch and put `Mage_Adminhtml.csv` file from that and apply patch it will work sure

Comment: Bro, initially i got 2 error, https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNLce.png. So I forget I have removed downloader, then i deleted the line https://snag.gy/rejqhl.jpg  from the patch. after i run the patch my error patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv Hunk #2 FAILED at 36. 1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv.rej

Comment: @zus do not delete anything from patch you just need to change  `Mage_Adminhtml.csv` file and put `downloader` as it is because its checking for `login.php` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69726/discussion-between-zus-and-mukesh-prajapati).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69734/discussion-between-zus-and-mukesh-prajapati).