# Patching Magento 1.9.2.0 with Security patch 9767

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, security, patches, supee-9767

I get one error trying to patch my Magento. Any ideas whats going on and how to fix it?

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 350 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 370 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 417 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 446 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 485 (offset 1 line).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 282 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 87 (offset -1 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 128 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 35 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 36.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 36 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/etc/config.xml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1202 (offset -83 lines).
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 401 (offset -6 lines).
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 28 (offset -2 lines).
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
patching file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 417 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 964 (offset -15 lines).
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 82 with fuzz 2.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 268 (offset -5 lines).
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
patching file js/varien/payment.js
patching file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
Hunk #1 succeeded at 711 (offset 27 lines).
```

Many thanks,
Rob

Comment: Your issue resolved? if yes then please look into my issue and suggest me to resolve...
https://stackoverflow.com/q/44413734/3820040

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml` does not match the expected version of the file. You probably modified it.

To fix that:

- Backup this file
- Download the original file of your Magento version
- Apply the patch
- Compare your backup with the new file
- Apply your custom changes to your custom theme `local.xml` or `page.xml`

Comment: Please look at my issue link below and suggest me to resolve if possible...
https://stackoverflow.com/q/44413734/3820040