# Issue while applying PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, magento1.9.2.4, supee-9767

I am facing issue while Applying `PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh` in Magento 1.9.2.4. Found below message after applying the patch. I am not aware of the steps to resolve the issue ... Please help me to resolve the issue.

I have seen below link but this is not working for me.

[Patching Magento 1.9.2.0 with Security Patch 9767](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/176946)

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 350 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 370 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 417 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 446 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 485 (offset 1 line).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 282 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 109 with fuzz 2.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 91 with fuzz 2.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 126 with fuzz 2.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 201 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 35 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 141 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 43 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 201 with fuzz 1 (offset 2 lines).
can't find file to patch at input line 900
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
|index 22a2fe6..b600f74 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
can't find file to patch at input line 925
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
|index bf6dfcc..6cab97a 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 93 with fuzz 2.
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 36 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 142 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 201 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 140 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1213 (offset -72 lines).
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 391 (offset -16 lines).
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
patching file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 417 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 964 (offset -15 lines).
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 82 with fuzz 2.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 268 (offset -5 lines).
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
patching file js/varien/payment.js
patching file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
Hunk #1 succeeded at 723 (offset 39 lines).
```

So the error is basically at file location :

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
```

Please suggest I should go for manual entry of the patching or not?

Comment: Try command line like putty, upload the patch to root folder, run by sh patchname.sh.,    successfully updated for mine.

Comment: @Rathinam tried your suggestion and again get above error... :(

Comment: could you share your command screen shots

Comment: take a look at this [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177598/53812)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that the following files are missing or unreadable:

- `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml`
- `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml`

Please double check that they're present in your install. If they are not, you'll have to download a fresh install of your Magento version and copy those files over.

If they are here, they're most likely unreadable so you should check the permissions of those files.

Comment: This works for me, as I download page.xml and /multishipping/addresses.phtml fresh from magento 1.9.2.4 and given desired permission and re-run the  patch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The above code are overwritten. Can you please check your Magento 1.9.2 core.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
app/etc/config.xml
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
downloader/Maged/Controller.php
downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

follow the link for more issues [Security Patch SUPEE-9767 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues)