# How to enable symlinks after SUPEE-9767 V2 install?

Tags: magento-1, supee-9767, symlinks

Its seems SUPEE-9767v2 has disabled and removed the option in *"Advanced -> Developer -> Template settings"*, that would allow us to enable/disable symlinks.

What is the other way to enable symlinks after V2 patch install?

Comment: How you install SUPEE-9767 V2, could you share the steps.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

<s>You can only do it on DB at the moment.</s>

## 1. SQL

Either ...

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '1' WHERE path = 'dev/template/allow_symlink';
```

Or if entry does not exist ...

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value)
VALUES (NULL , 'default', '0', 'dev/template/allow_symlink', '1');
```

*Note: Don't forget to add table prefix if you use one.*

## 2. Script

Or run this from magento root ...

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('dev/template/allow_symlink', '1', 'default', 0);
```

## 3. local.xml

Add another XML to `app/etc/` directory like `local.SUPEE-9767.xml` to override `local.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <default>
        <dev>
            <template>
                <allow_symlink>1</allow_symlink>
            </template>
        </dev>
    </default>
</config>
```

## 4. "Module"

Create a mini "extension" with this `system.xml` to bring back config option to admin backend:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <dev>
            <groups>
                <template>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <fields>
                        <allow_symlink>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <backend_model>core/config_data</backend_model>
                        </allow_symlink>
                    </fields>
                </template>
            </groups>
        </dev>
    </sections>
</config>
```

<s>Add an empty class for `backend_model` to [enable save](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Symlink.php#L40-L43) config value.</s> Thanks to @colinmollenhour, instead of an empty class just reset backend model to parent.

<sup>**Download:** https://github.com/sreichel/magento-StackExchange_AllowSymlink</sup>

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way is to use [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) which is a very useful command line dev tool for Magento

Toggle symlinks on or off for all store views with

```
n98-magerun.phar dev:symlinks 0
```

To check if symlinks are enabled use

```
n98-magerun.phar config:dump | grep symlink
```

Answer (score 1):

IN patch **9767 v2**

Below code Updated in file

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml`

```
--- app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
@@ -601,18 +601,19 @@
                 <label>Template Settings</label>
                 <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                 <sort_order>25</sort_order>
-                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
-                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
-                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
+                    <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
+                    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
+                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                 <fields>
                     <allow_symlink translate="label comment">
                         <label>Allow Symlinks</label>
                         <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                         <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
+                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_symlink</backend_model>
                         <sort_order>10</sort_order>
-                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
-                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
-                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
+                            <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
+                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
+                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                         <comment>Warning! Enabling this feature is not recommended on production environments because it represents a potential security risk.</comment>
                     </allow_symlink>
                 </fields>
```

Just Update this field  `<show_in_default>0</show_in_default>` to `1`

and you will see that setting again

> Once you done revert this file

Comment: Isn't this V1? In V2 this lines are back, but `<show_in_default>` is set to 0. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @sv3n oh My bad I am seeing v1 code, give me 2 min I will update my answer

Comment: @sv3n I have updated the answer

Comment: You shouldn't edit core files. You can easily override this setting in many other ways...

Comment: @7ochem I dont know how to override `system.xml` if you have any tutorial then please give me

Comment: Worth to mention the added `backend_model` that prevents saving this field to DB.

Comment: @sv3n thanks for update I forgot we can do that way , thanks man