# Magento 1.9 fresh install missing follow symlinks "Template Settings"

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, symlinks

I'm running a magento 1.9 fresh install in a **Debian 9** (also fresh install) and I can't find the "**Template Settings**". It should be under `System > Configuration > Advanced > Template`, but it is not there.

I'm looking for this section to set the "**Allow Symlinks**" to On, but it is not there. Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Magento 1.9.3.4 / SUPEE-9767 symlinks are disabled (and config option is hidden) by default. You can only change it on DB at the moment:

Either ...

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '1' WHERE path = 'dev/template/allow_symlink';
```

Or if entry does not exist ...

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value)
VALUES (NULL , 'default', '0', 'dev/template/allow_symlink', '1');
```

*Note: Don't forget to add table prefix if you use one.*

Or run this from magento root ...

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('dev/template/allow_symlink', '1', 'default', 0);
```

---

- [Security Patch SUPEE-9767 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176958/46249)
- [How to enable symlinks after SUPEE-9767 V2 install?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184184/how-to-enable-symlinks-after-supee-9767-v2-install/184185#184185)