# patch 9767 forgot to disable symlinks

Tags: magento-1.9

> I forgot to disable symlync before apply to patch 9767 now if i enable
>   form key validation my checkout is not working .can you please assist
>   me now what i have to do

Comment: See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184184/how-to-enable-symlinks-after-supee-9767-v2-install  - this may help

Answer (score 0):

You can edit symlink setting from database. For that in **core_config_data** table find " **dev/template/allow_symlink** ".

If that is exist in table then change value to 0.

If row not exist then add new row into table

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`config_id`, `scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES (NULL , 'default', '0', 'dev/template/allow_symlink', '1');
```

That's it.

Comment: But after upgrade i am not able to see that settings in admin i read some blog without disable if you will upgrade there are config overrides happen

Comment: If you see template setting in admin side then you need to change system setting from " code -> core -> etc -> system.xml " and change " show_in_default " 0 to 1 for " Template Settings " and " Allow Symlinks ".

Comment: can you please tell me is there any major impact