# SUPEE-9767 Error

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-9767

When I trying to apply SUPEE-9767 in my Magento Community Edition 1.9.0.1 getting following error.

```
./PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.0.1_v1-2017-05-25-09-15-34.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Web/Secure/Offloaderheader.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 306 (offset 22 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 574 (offset 45 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 854 (offset 55 lines).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 1355.
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 36.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 54.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
The next patch would create the file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1197 (offset -16 lines).
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 399 (offset 8 lines).
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
checking file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
The next patch would create the file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.map,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
checking file js/varien/payment.js
checking file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

Comment: I fixed issue myself

Comment: can you please share the link from where you download the related files of patch 9767 for the Magento CE 1.9.0.1? Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

A reason could be that you modified the following files:

- `app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml`
- `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml`

To fix that:

- Backup those files
- Download the original files of your Magento version
- Apply the patch
- Compare your backups with the new files
- Copy the new patched files to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml` and `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/page.xml` (ideally you might want to apply your custom changes in a `local.xml` file for this one)
- Apply your custom changes to those new copied files

Comment: presume you mean "A reason could be that you **modified** the following files"

Comment: @jscar yes sorry ^^

Comment: Still, am facing the same issue during patch update

Answer (score 0):

```
  app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
  app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
```

I think you have modified above two files manually that's why you facing problem

So for both file follow this instruction

1) take backup of current file

2) revert this two file with orignal one

3) apply patch and manually do those changes which is in this two files

Comment: I haven't changed above core files & I did check by removing existing files by adding original source from Magento 1.9.0.1... No luck

Answer (score 0):

Download original files for these files (backup first)

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
```

if you already did it and you tried to re-applied the patch you could be getting

```
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

message it means that the patch is supposed to create that file in my case I just deleted (backup first) after deleting those files the patch was applied successfully.

Delete all files that are getting (1 out of 1 hunk ignored) message:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Web/Secure/Offloaderheader.php
js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js
js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.map
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
```

Remember to run if patch was applied successfully:

```
php -f shell/compiler.php clear
php -f shell/compiler.php compile
```

Comment: Jelqui Everything seems fine except following

Comment: 2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

Comment: Did you download  originals files for

    app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
    app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml

Also, delete files that are getting hunk ignored 
after doing that run the patch

Comment: I managed to install patch successfully. Once patch applied successfully forgot password page not working in our custom theme...