# Magento 1.9.3.3 one page checkout - Unable to go ahead of Payment Information tab

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, checkout-page, magento-1.9.3.3

I am using default Magento one page checkout. on checkout page I am unable to continue to "Order Review" tab.

[image: Please Review this Image for more info]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ohh, Found solution immediately after raising the question. I just need to disable form key validation from backend and it's working fine now.

To disable form key validation Go to:
**System > Configuration > Advanced > Security > Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout**

and change the value to **No**.

That's it!

I found solution from below link.

[SUPEE-9767 Magento CE 1.9.3.3 Onestep Checkout not working with Form Key Validation On Checkout enabled](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176984/supee-9767-magento-ce-1-9-3-3-onestep-checkout-not-working-with-form-key-validat)

Comment: Mark this as the answer if it solved your problem - helps anyone else that's searching for solutions.

Comment: Changing that config makes the issue go away, but having `Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout` set to "yes" is better, from a security perspective.  Take a look at solutions offered here, so you can get this feature turned on https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/Checkout-Stuck-on-Step-4-after-SUPEE-9767-with-Formkey/td-p/68018.

Comment: The recommended solution is installing SUPEE-9767 Version 2 patch.

Comment: As a temporary solution - This is fine. But the solution to fixing the issue, disagree. You should of looked at the JS file.

Answer (score 2):

This is most probably the issue related to checkout Javascript code.

- Open `skin/frontend/<package>/<theme>/js/opcheckout.js`
- Find the line:

  ```
  if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]') {
  ```
- Change it to:

  ```
  if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]' || elements[i].name == 'form_key') {
  ```
- Save the file.
- Clear Cache from Magento Admin (System -> Cache Management).
- Clear your browser's Cache as well.

This should solve the issue.

Alternatively, you can also try running this patch:

Magento SUPEE-9767 Checkout Form Key Theme Patch: https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b