# Magento Checkout hangs on Step One

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

After I've updated a shop from 1.8.0.0 to 1.9.3.3 I'm not able to get past step 1 of the checkout. Logical explanation would be the form_key issue and I've thoroughly investigated the possibility of this causing the problems. As far as I can see it doesn't, at least not directly... Either with the form_key setting enabled or disable I get the same result: no step 2.

When I look at the console of Firefox I get this message:

```
Call to undefined method Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled () in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php on line 373
```

The referenced code looks like this:

```
if ($this->isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled() && !$this->_validateFormKey()) {
  return;
}
```

Obviously if I delete the first part my checkout works again but this can't be solution.

Apparently I'm missing something here. Checkout is not able to verify the form_key setting or something? Anybody who has experience with this kind of issue?

Comment: Check with https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176984/supee-9767-magento-ce-1-9-3-3-onestep-checkout-not-working-with-form-key-validat

Comment: I've check the post several times but I can't get it to relate with my issue but I'm sure I'm overlooking something. The issues at hand is mentioned but the solution is not very advisable imho.