# Magento 1.9.2.2 SUPEE-9767 Patch ERROR

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-9767

Below is the error log:

```
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 350 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 370 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 417 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 446 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 485 (offset 1 line).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 282 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 500.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 35 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 36 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/etc/config.xml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1281 (offset -4 lines).
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 404 (offset -3 lines).
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
patching file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 417 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 964 (offset -15 lines).
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 82 with fuzz 2.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 268 (offset -5 lines).
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
patching file js/varien/payment.js
patching file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
Hunk #1 succeeded at 711 (offset 27 lines).
```

I have confirmed that app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php core file is unchanged. Still, the patch is giving error.

Comment: Check the permissions on this file. Also checks that the previous patches were applied.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism how can i find what patch missing during installing the new patch?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism you can check the list of applied patches in "app/etc/applied.patches.list" file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty Sure that you are getting error in this file `checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php` because of following two reasons:

**1st reason :**

You Have not applied `SUPEE-7405` : In this case first Apply `SUPEE-7405` and then Apply this patch

**2nd Reason:**

You have manually modified this file: in this case download `magento 1.9.3` and revert this file from that version and apply this patch after that again put your custom code into that.

> I Advice you to not to modify core files instead rewriting the
>   classes

Comment: FYI, I did not modify core file. @Murtuza, I have downloaded a file from Magento 1.9.3 and reverted, This time patch applied successfully. It looks like this patch has issue with app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php core file of Magento version 1.9.2.2.

Comment: @BrijeshKapletiya Have you successfully applied 7405 patch ?

Comment: @BrijeshKapletiya if my answer helps you then mark as accepted so other users who has same problem take benefit from this

Comment: I directly added a file from version 1.9.3 and applied patch.

Comment: @BrijeshKapletiya let remain complete answer as it is if some one has some other issue, they will get benefit

Comment: guys, the issue is not solved. After replaced by fresh magento file still not solve the patch issue, Issue :: patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Unreversed patch detected! Ignore -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv.rej. Overall error :: https://justpaste.it/1e9pn