# Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully... ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-9767

Trying to apply newly released patch on our Magento EE 1.9.3.2 but getting the following error.

```
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 350 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 370 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 417 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 446 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 485 (offset 1 line).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 282 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
can't find file to patch at input line 351
```

Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:

```
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|index 06fa6b1..717fd4d 100644
|--- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 500.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 121 (offset 2 lines).
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 35 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 36 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/etc/config.xml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1281 (offset -6 lines).
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 406 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
checking file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 417 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 964 (offset -15 lines).
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 82 with fuzz 2.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 268 (offset -5 lines).
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
checking file js/varien/payment.js
checking file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
Hunk #1 succeeded at 731 (offset 47 lines).
```

Comment: Might be worth checking here. Normally this happens if previous patches are not applied or core files are modified. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176995/magento-1-9-2-2-supee-9767-patch-error

Comment: Did you apply Supee-9767 V1? If so you need to revert that one first then apply V2. Also as Harri said, make sure you have all the previous patches applied too.

Comment: this issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

1) Compare this file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php` is differ from the core file. download Magento 1.9.3.2 and check any changes in this file.

2) We understand the meaning of **Hunk #1 succeeded at 350 (offset 1 line)**. 
 if the file to be patched has changed slightly or any space since the patch was created, but the specific section remained the same, patch can detect that and apply the patch appropriately.

That means the file was successfully patched, but the first section that was patched was 350 lines earlier than was originally specified.

It is same for **Hunk #{number} succeeded** items