# Magento Watermark have black background when transparent

Tags: magento-1.9, watermark

I've updated to the last version of magento. 
Then I changed my watermark that was transparent.
Now I see a black background instead of the transparency. I tryed to find some solution, like to create another Gd2.php, but it doesn't work... What can I try?

Comment: Please check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177005/watermark-get-black-background-when-transparent/177032#177032

Comment: I see yet that solution, it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer here (same as comment link just a different answer) -
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177402/54922

My product png image upload was giving me the same black background. SUPEE-9767 (and the newest magento) extends the validate function in the image upload.

As I do not have enough reputation to comment, thats why I am adding this as an answer.