# Image Background Gets Black after installing patch SUPEE-9767

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-9767

I have installed patch SUPEE-9767 on 1.9.2.1 store, Now the new products images is having a black color around it. I attached a sample product image.

I have tried this fix

[Watermark get black background when transparent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177005/watermark-get-black-background-when-transparent/179485#179485)

but the problem is after I update the new code in Validator/Image.php I cannot upload images from the admin, I can use the browse button and click Upload but after that it's just showing 'uploading' forever

Would some one advice me how to fix this issue

[image: product image]

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this bug as well. I have applied a fix to the `Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image` class and was looking for a place to submit a bug report and patch for this.

In between lines 96 and 97, I have added this small check for PNG and GIF type images to preserve the alpha channel of the image:

```
if ($fileType == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $fileType == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
    imagecolortransparent($img, imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127));
    imagealphablending($img, false);
    imagesavealpha($img, true);
}
```

I have tested this and can confirm it works when adding images to a product from the catalogue view. If you implement this, please let me know if it works for you as well.