# Transparency resizing Magento 1 Configurable Swatches

Tags: magento-1.9

Trying to make swatches transperant. Right now when swatches get resized, they get a black background. I found this file app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php with the following code inside:

```
if (!is_null($image)) {
    $filename = $image->getFile();
    $swatchImage = $this->_resizeSwatchImage($filename, 'product', $width, $height);
    $swatchType = 'product';
    $url = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $swatchImage;
}

return $url;
```

Is it possible to change this code to keep the transperancy? Thanks. (using Magento 1.9.3.3)

Note: This isn't the same issue as the app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php file, where product images were getting black backgrounds discussed at [Watermark get black background when transparent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177005/watermark-get-black-background-when-transparent).