# SUPEE-9767 Error CE 1.8.0.0

Tags: magento-1.8

when i patch my CE 1.8.0.0 i get the following errors.
It cant be patched it seems with the latest security patch.

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 109 (offset -29 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Web/Secure/Offloaderheader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
can't find file to patch at input line 422
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|index 7f7b9d0..cbbcbb1 100644
|--- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
Hunk #3 succeeded at 1325 (offset -10 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 488.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Resource/Calculation.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/etc/config.xml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
checking file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 400 (offset -5 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 923 (offset -5 lines).
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
Hunk #3 succeeded at 242 with fuzz 2 (offset -13 lines).
checking file downloader/template/login.phtml
checking file js/varien/payment.js
checking file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty Sure that you are getting error in this file `checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php` because of following two reasons:

**1st reason :**

You Have not applied `SUPEE-7405` : In this case first Apply `SUPEE-7405` and then Apply this patch

**2nd Reason:**

You have manually modified this file: in this case download `magento 1.9.3` and revert this file from that version and apply this patch after that again put your custom code into that.