# SUPEE-9767 Magento 1.6.0.0

Tags: magento-1.6, redirection, supee-9767

After patching a Magento 1.6.0.0 site with SUPEE-9767 I am getting an infinite redirect loop.

There were no errors applying the patch.

I am running it on Apache2.2 with PHP 5.4 on CentOS 6.

The site has 2 stores on it, not sure if that could be causing it?

The logs show that it is doing a bunch of 302 redirects:

```
{IP_ADDRESS} - - [02/Jun/2017:11:09:52 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
{IP_ADDRESS} - - [02/Jun/2017:11:09:52 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
{IP_ADDRESS} - - [02/Jun/2017:11:09:52 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
{IP_ADDRESS} - - [02/Jun/2017:11:09:52 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
{IP_ADDRESS} - - [02/Jun/2017:11:09:53 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identified the root cause of this issue. It was apparently because of these lines

**Quick Fix**

Find the below lines inside the method ***protected function _checkBaseUrl($request)*** in the file ***app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php***

```
 if (isset($uri['scheme']) && $uri['scheme'] != $request->getScheme()
        || isset($uri['host']) && $uri['host'] != $request->getHttpHost()
        || isset($uri['path']) && strpos($requestUri, $uri['path']) === false
 ) {
```

Change these lines to

```
 if (isset($uri['host']) && $uri['host'] != $request->getHttpHost()
            || isset($uri['path']) && strpos($requestUri, $uri['path']) === false
 ) {
```

After that save the file (commit to your REPO), clear the cache (remove everything inside var/cache folder) and reload your store front. You should find the site loads without anymore 302 redirect issues after applying the SUPEE 9767 Patch.

**Root Cause**

The difference in SCHEME value between the actual Request and the URI after redirection. Eg: The actual request returns the scheme HTTP but the scehme in the URI can be HTTPS

**Possible Underlying Reasons**

1. You may most likely have a redirect rule in .htaccess file to redirect all the http requests to https.
2. Both the base secure and unsecure URLs begin with https

Comment: It was `Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()` changed to `Mage::getConfig()->shouldUrlBeSecure($request->getPathInfo())` in line 303 (308 after patch) of that file. It now does not think that / needs to be secured when I visit the site using https://. It redirects to http:// but then apache forces it to https:// causing the loop.