# Magento Patch 9767 "Decoding failed: Syntax error"

Tags: magento-enterprise, patches, zend-framework, json, supee-9767

I am running EE 1.14.0.1 and PHP 5.6 and got below error on production server only. I cleared the cache and implement the solutions suggested by  @folektoras133 at [Security Patch SUPEE-9767 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177036/2374). nothing worked. Any suggestion ?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:29:"Decoding failed: Syntax error";i:1;s:1397:"#0 //htdoc/app/code/local/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php(178): Zend_Json::decode('a:0:{}')
packet_write_wait: Connection to 52.26.63.162 port 22: Broken pipegeCache/Model/logouter.php(214): Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Observer->_loadDesignExceptions()
Saving session.../htdoc/app/code/local/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/...copying shared history...e_PageCache_Model_Observer->_saveDesignException()
...saving history...truncating history files...core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1339...completed._PageCache_Model_Observer->cacheResponse(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
[Process completed]#4 //htdoc/app/code/core/Mage/Core): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Observer), 'cacheResponse', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 //htdoc/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_fron...', Array)
#6 //htdoc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(182): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_fron...', Array)
#7 //htdoc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 //htdoc/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 //htdoc/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}";s:3:"url";s:161:"/product_page?utm_source=google_shopping&gclid=CjwKEAjwgtTJBRDRmd6ZtLrGyxwSJAA7Fy-hBnSgpddfHXC9mP9HkKPPk3WbbtZfbd7voy-K2NSd5BoC0eLw_wcB";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. We are using Redis Caching. So I had to disable the default caching on production Magento. Once I did that the site worked fine. Also another thing to be take in consideration we have multiple AWS EC2 instances running on production. but one EC2 instance for development. I am not sure why this would cause the problem but its solved now.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is the "Default" cache? Can you explain more on this? Do we need to disable Magento's default caching(i.e. Configuration, Layouts, Blocks HTML output, Translations, Collections Data, EAV types and attributes, Web Services Configuration, Web Services Configuration, Amasty Improved Navigation)

Comment: yes, you need to disable them because they are conflicting with Redis.

Comment: But if we disable the default cache then how redis will work? Redis get same cache data from default cache right?