# PATCH SUPEE 9767 Can't be applied

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-9767

When I apply the above patch it is getting stuck at app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml at line 120. I have looked at the patch file and the code is

```
diff --git 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
index 4ee6d76..47c3a79 100644
--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
@@ -120,6 +120,7 @@
                 <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?></span></span>
             </button>
         </div>
+            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
     </form>
     <?php endif; ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
```

Why is the error appearing?

Edit: Question is asking in the case of identical files.

Comment: it seems you've modified that file, you need to reset that file to its original code

Comment: I have just reset the file to its original and am still receiving the same message?

Comment: try install dos2unix, and  in terminal go to project path and try run `dos2unix app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`

Comment: You put me on the right track. It must have been an invisible character or something. I downloaded the original version of Magento and copied the file and then the patch applied successfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-9767 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues)

Comment: Issue is asking about identical files which is not explained on claimed duplicate page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When applying patch, make sure you did not change the magento core code, if there is an error for a specific file, try to download the original Magento file and replace the error file. If you are migrating from windows to Unix/Linux machine, some of the core code will have end of line issue, therefore you need to reformat it to unix format, for this case i install dos2unix to fix the end of line problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because that file is not as Magento is expecting it to be. It appears that it has been modified to put the formkey in it. If you have a look at [Security Patch SUPEE-9767 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues?rq=1) you'll see what you need to do