# Error while applying security patch SUPEE-7405 V0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-7405

I'm trying to install patch `SUPEE-7405` on my development site and got this error:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully... ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Admin.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/PaymentController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php Hunk #1 FAILED at 135. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php Hunk #1 succeeded at 234 (offset -5 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowadvancedController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/Salesrule.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Order.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/authorizenet/directpost/iframe.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/options/type/file.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/creditmemo/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/renderer/default.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals/discount.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
checking file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
checking file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
Done
```

Can anyone help me this issue.

Comment: see this [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177598/53812)

Comment: What version of magento is this? and are you using SUPEE 7405 V1.1?

Comment: Magento 1.9.2.1 and i'm installing SUPEE 7405

Comment: Which patches are currently installed?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below steps:

-> If your htaccess file have change then Restore it default .htaccess file temporarily.

-> Before you apply patch you need confirm that core files should not have change.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi @Hardik thank you for you response, but still it doesn't work. I also chekced this file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

Answer (score 0):

This is normally due to modifications in files within your core to those that the patch was expecting. This can be due to previous patches not being installed or files being modified in other ways.

Error is showing that below files are not as expected i believe:

```
checking file 
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php Hunk #1 FAILED at 135. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php Hunk #1 succeeded at 234 (offset -5 lines).
```

Check all previous patches are installed by going through all patches available for your version of magento and installing the ones not installed from earliest to newest. You can check the applied patches in applied.patches.list within app/etc.

If this still does not work check these files match original core files for your Magento Version and revert these files to original versions if they do not match.