# SUPEE-9767 Patch/CE 1.9.3.3 + checkout form validation breaks multishipping in default theme

Tags: supee-9767, magento-1.9.3.3

On a clean install of CE 1.9.3.3, multishipping is broken when using the default theme and enabling checkout form key validation.

How to reproduce:

1. Change the theme from `rwd` to `default`
2. Enable the `Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout` setting
3. Add a product to the cart and go the `checkout/cart` page.
4. Click on "Checkout with Multiple Addresses" to go to the `checkout/multishipping/addresses` page.
5. On this page, observe that the following buttons do not have any effect:

   - "Enter a New Address"
   - "Update Qty & Addresses"
   - "Continue to Shipping Information"

This issue is also present on previous Magento versions with SUPEE-9767 installed.

Answer (score 4):

Magento forgot to add the `formkey` block to the following template:

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml`

Magento should fix this in an update of the SUPEE-9767 patch (and the CE 1.9.3.3 release), but in the meantime, the issue can be circumvented by adding the following line just somewhere between the `<form>` and `</form>` tags of this template and all overrides (if any) of this template:

`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml("formkey") ?>`

Comment: To clarify, it code snippet needs to be inserted between the <form> </form> tags. Safest bet is to insert it just before </form>.

Comment: Thanks, "<form>" and "</form>" were not shown my answer (only in the source). This is fixed now.