# SUPEE PATCH - 9767 error in checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-9767

i have applied **SUPEE PATCH 9767** into my Magento 1.9 environment. Im using my custom theme for my store, before applying the patch there was no error in the checkout page. But after applying the patch the checkout page freezes at the Billing information . If i fill address and click on Continue - it justs shows the loading next step buffer and nothing happens. I checked in the Console also, there was no error thrown. can anyone explain what is happening?

---

**Note**: If i revert back the patch , the checkout is working fine

Comment: did you add form key to your form in your custom theme template?

Comment: @John no i have not added any form key to my form, i just applied the patch that's all

Comment: Please check: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the form key has not been added to your custom theme templates.

To add them, use this little script : https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b

Comment: it worked!!! i just ran that .sh file and the issue got fixed, thank you

Comment: @Guruprasad you're welcome

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism, you have good reputation. pls help me to sort out my problem..  I have waste my 5 hour almost, Pls look into it => https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180021/unable-to-login-admin-panel

Answer (score 2):

Formkey may be missing in your theme. Please check in your theme for following file.

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>



 /app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
```

Answer (score 2):

patch 9767 adds form keys to the following forms:

**Shipping cart form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`

**Multishipping billing checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml`

**Multishipping shipping checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml`

**Billing checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

**Shipping checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml`

**Payment checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml`

**Shipping method checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml`

**Persistent Billing checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

What to do:

If you're using with custom versions of those templates you'll have to update them by adding the following code into them:

`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>`

For more reference, 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176958

Answer (score 0):

Also include form key in this file for multiaddress shipping

app/design/frontend/YourPackage/Yourtheme/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml