# Unable to login admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

I am not able to login admin panel after filling the right credential.
Googling over internet, i found solution.

To resolve this issue, someone suggest:

Go to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php file within your magento directory.

Find the code:

```
session_set_cookie_params($this->getCookie()->getLifetime(),$this->getCookie()->getPath(),$this->getCookie()->getDomain(),$this->getCookie()->isSecure(),$this->getCookie()->getHttponly());
```

& replace with

```
session_set_cookie_params($this->getCookie()->getLifetime(),$this->getCookie()->getPath()//$this->getCookie()->getDomain(),//$this->getCookie()->isSecure(),//$this->getCookie()->getHttponly());
```

**Is this a proper solution ??**

---------xxxxxxx-----------xxxxxxxxxx----------xxxxxxxxxxx---------

**Updated 1 =>**

Whenever I free up space by manually deleting cache and session things work fine for a day maximum and then again login stop working.

**Updated 2 =>**
I know , there is space related problem. Whenever i am trying to create new folder in the root using command prompt.
**Message:**

[image]

However, 1.4 GB is available on server.

Comment: any error message is showing?

Comment: No, before it is work and currently not working. check what is the problem need to check. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel
check this link

Comment: Increase the space in your server. 1.4 is available in your server. but Magento directory have no space. Increase space it will work

Answer (score 1):

**This is definitely a space issue**. As your **Magento install does not have enough space to create the session files, you cannot login anymore**. You have to double check if your disk has got partitions and double check where is installed your Magento website. I strongly suggest you contact your hosting provider or your dev ops guy for that if you're not confident with server management.

Comment: someone suggest save session into DB instead of files.. Is this proper way to save session into DB. & this solution can solve space problem ???

Comment: After googling, I got to know that saving session in DB can hurt the database performance & also affect the site speed.