# Magento patch 9767 shipping method

Tags: magento-1, shipping, supee-9767

After installing patch SUPEE-9767 and enabling Form Key Validation in checkout page, the shipping method step cannot proceed to next step.

After disabling the Form Key Validation in admin it's working fine.

Please find the below screenshots.

[image]

I want to show like this:

[image]

Thanks
Bestregards

Answer (score 2):

patch 9767 adds form keys to the following forms:

**Shipping cart form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`

**Multishipping billing checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml`

**Multishipping shipping checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml`

**Billing checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

**Shipping checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml`

**Payment checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml`

**Shipping method checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml`

**Persistent Billing checkout form:**

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

What to do:

If you're using with custom versions of those templates you'll have to update them by adding the following code into them:

`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>`

For more reference, 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176958

Answer (score 1):

Your custom theme templates are most likely missing the form key update.

To fix that, I suggest you run the following script: https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b

Answer (score 1):

As said in the other post, this patch adds form keys to the following forms:

**Shipping cart form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
```

Billing checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

**Shipping checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
```

**Payment checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
```

**Shipping method checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
```

**Persistent Billing checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

On top of that the following JS files have been updated to be compatible with that change:

```
js/varien/payment.js
skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

**What to do:**

If you're using with custom versions of those templates you'll have to update them by adding the following code into them:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

If you're using a 3rd party checkout module, you'll have to get in touch with them so they can provide an updated version of their module.