# Checkout Failing after SUPEE-9767 on 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, supee-9767

I see a lot of issues around said patch. Onepage-checkout wont progress past billing form.

I checked all the `.phtml` forms and ensured they had the form key code. They do. The form key field is seen in browser inspection. I haves both turned on and off **"enable form key validation"** no change. I think i have done every thing i has seen in the forums I am at a loss. I can't revert the patch as the `-R  option` doesn't work. I may have to go to backups.

Any thoughts?

Comment: are you sure all your caches have been cleared including css/js and fpc caches? With the form key validation disabled the presence of the form key at one page checkout is irrelevant. Have you checked the system logs for errors?

Comment: All caches cleared including js/css from admin, var.cache cleared..  and yes i would have thought if not enabled the code shoudln't have any affect.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please enable the Path hint in admin. Double check the all phtml files having the key code in your template files

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

Please double check in the following files.

Shipping cart form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
```

Multishipping billing checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
```

Multishipping shipping checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
```

Billing checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

Shipping checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
```

Payment checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
```

Shipping method checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
```

Persistent Billing checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

For More Reference

[Security Patch SUPEE-9767 - Possible issues](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues)

**Note**

*You can use git private repository for handling the codes. it would be easy to revert the files*

Comment: Thanks , did all that and all the phtml were fine.. I moved the form code to before the /form and before the /fieldlist and other variations. no avail.. In any case the i switched off the security feature in admin and made no change. In teh end I gave up and reverted teh code to pre 9767 and its all fine now and I will give 9767 some shelf time and try again later

Comment: Yes this link is helpfull form keys are missing in theme files, check the form key under theme files

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use the Aoe_TemplateHints module to see which templates are being loaded and check the `form_key` is being passed in your [browser inspector](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177154/24534). I found another module was responsible, Paypal_InContext, though disabled in admin the template was still loading at the payment options section.