# Unable to Upload Product Images 1.9.3.3

Tags: product-images, image-upload, upload, magento-1.9.3.3

I am unable to find any solution that will work for my issue so I need to post the question.

I recently upgraded to 1.9.3.3 and now the Browse button does nothing when clicked when trying to upload product images.

I also tried the Maven HTML5 uploader and it throws a Disallowed file type error (file type is a jpg).

Just not sure what do do next. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Please check this post: [Security Patch SUPEE-9767 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues)

---

For image upload errors read this:

## Image Upload callback

The image gallery controller has been updated to add a validation callback.

### What to do

If you're using a custom module that does image upload with code that looks like this:

```
    $uploader = new Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader('image');
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
    $uploader->addValidateCallback('catalog_product_image',
        Mage::helper('catalog/image'), 'validateUploadFile');
    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
```

I strongly suggest you update that code by adding the following piece after it:

```
    $uploader->addValidateCallback(
        Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image::NAME,
        Mage::getModel('core/file_validator_image'),
        'validate'
    );
```

Comment: Hi sv3n. Before trying the Maven module I was attempting the basic out of the box product upload process. When it didn't work I tried the Maven module. However, I have since uninstalled it hoping to get the basic Magento uploader to work.

Comment: @CamdenRoe could you solve it? If the Maven module has its own fileuploader search for it in code and add the lines posted above.

Comment: $uploader = new Maven_Html5uploader_Model_Media_Uploader();
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
$uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
$uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);$uploader->addValidateCallback(
        Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image::NAME,
        Mage::getModel('core/file_validator_image'),
        'validate'
    );
            $result = $uploader->save( Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseTmpMediaPath()); this my code aftter adding your answer but still not working