# Magento Patch: 9767 after install admin show Invalid Form Key

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

I install the security patch: 9767 on Magento version 1.9.3.0

after that, all forms like admin login form, customer login form, cart etc
all are working stop as well as admin show me error like **Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.**

I also revert the patch file manually one by one, but still, I face the issue
please help if you know the way.

Comment: remove cache and session once

Comment: I alredy tried this

Answer (score 0):

I think you have enabled Form Key Validation On Checkout.

Please follow instructions given in below thread.

[Security Patch SUPEE-9767 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues)