# magento 1.9.3.4 and patch 9767v2 issue

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

We have upgraded to magento 1.9.3.4 and we have custom theme , in the custom theme we have uploaded patch files and in the payment.phtml file we have kept formkey under fieldset.

But issue is after payment method selected it is not continued to place order.

Comment: Try this link it will be helpful https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b#file-add-checkout-form-key-sh

Comment: Please follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues

Answer (score 0):

Check how you have added the formkey in payment.phtml, the formkey should be outside of the fieldset element, but within the form element like this

```
<form action="" id="co-payment-form">
    <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
</form>
```

Makes sure your caches have been refreshed, and your browser is showing the formkey during checkout.

[image]

Comment: ok thanks but i am unable to find the symlink location at admin.

Comment: also i kept the formkey under filedset and in the console iam able to view the formkey

Comment: Are you using modman for extensions?

Comment: in billing, shipping info,  shipping methods steps iam able to see the form_key...but in payment when i click next step form_key is not showing in the console

Comment: what is modam? i dont know about this

Comment: symlinks are not affecting you, ignore that. If you are certain the formkey has been added to your template file then you need to find out what is disabling it at checkout.

Comment: i also checked logs but unable to find the issue... For other sites all worked well only for specific site this is not working

Comment: after trying this link this worked https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b#file-add-checkout-form-key-sh

Comment: @EwallTester good! Obviously you had overlooked a custom template file without a formkey entry.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this problem in chrome, but I think that it can be in others. 
If look at form_key output, you can see that input with form_key has "disabled" property. 
Clean browser cache and check again, "disabled" property will now disappear and checkout works fine.
It looks like browser caching issue.

Comment: yes i removed browser cache and tested in chrome. But same issue..Anyhow this is fixed by following this link https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b#file-add-checkout-form-key-sh