# upgrading from Magento version 1.9.3.1 to v1.9.3.4

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, supee-9767

I need to upgrade from Magento version 1.9.3.1 to v1.9.3.4 which includes version 2 of SUPEE-9767.  And just want to check that the normal upgrade process I have is correct.

1. Make back up of website & DB.
2. Test upgrade on staging website first by merging latest version of Magento (v1.9.3.4) with current website codebase.
3. Test upgrade has completed by logging into admin panel and checking version number.
4. Test website, cart, checkout, product pages, product listings etc.
5. Add maintenance.flag to production website to put it in maintenance mode.
6. Make same changes on Production (i.e. merging latest version of Magento  with current website codebase.)
7. Remove maintenance.flag from production and test upgrade has been successful.

Does this seem ok?
Is it ok that I'm skipping two small release inbetween by going directly from 1.9.3.1 to v1.9.3.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are proceeding is correct.

In v1.9.3.4 all the release are added. Dont worry about small release.

**Note:** After upgrade, **Billing,Shipping,Add to cart and Payment** not working Please check your form, `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml(“formkey”) ?>` is there. if not please add.

> ```
> <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
> ```

```
/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml    
/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
```

Hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, do you know which templates I should check to see if `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>` is missing? Is this a known issue for this upgrade?

Comment: if enable Enable Symlinks  yes in backend.  we need to pass formkey. otherwise not. Enable Symlinks  path is
System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Template Settings > Enable Symlinks

Comment: i will update the file list in ans :)

Comment: the $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') is update in core theme (base,rwa,defualt). We need to past in our overwrite theme.

for detail https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues/176881#176881

Comment: `Allow Symlinks` is set to `No` on our site :)

Comment: No problem it will work. if any issue please post in question i will help you :)

Comment: asked a related question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/184351/6549), any thoughts?

Comment: i will check and provide ans :)