# Magento upgrade to 1.9.3.4 - is forms working without form_key output in templates

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, form-key, magento-1.9.3.4

I've just upgraded to Magento v1.9.3.4 and have *Enabled Form Key Validation On Checkout* as recommended.  Magento also advices:

> Important! Enabling this option means that your custom templates used
>   in checkout process contain form_key output. Otherwise checkout may
>   not work.

However, even though we're using **Idev_OneStepCheckout** module which does not have `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>` in any of it's templates our checkout still works.  And I can complete a purchase.

**Am I testing it correctly, could the upgrade have failed some how?** Perhaps, I should not be worried as everything is working but I don't understand why when our template don't include the form_key output.

I've searched the base directory and can see where the `formkey` is used in each of these templates, which are almost all overridden in our theme or another extension:

```
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:43: 
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml:112:
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/checkout/cart.phtml:50:
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml:94: 
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/checkout/multishipping/overview.phtml:34: 
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml:129:
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml:204: 
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/checkout/onepage/login.phtml:69: 
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml:40: 
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml:144:
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml:46:  
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/customer/address/edit.phtml:42:
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/customer/form/edit.phtml:33:  
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/customer/form/login.phtml:42:
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/customer/form/newsletter.phtml:34:
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login-simple.phtml:42:  
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login.phtml:39:  
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/opc/customer/form/login.phtml:54:
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/opc/onepage/login.phtml:14:  
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml:202: 
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml:75:
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml:41: 
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/review/form.phtml:31:   
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/sales/reorder/sidebar.phtml:41:   
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/sendfriend/send.phtml:74:   
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/wishlist/sharing.phtml:33: 
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/wishlist/view.phtml:42: 
app/design/frontend/base//default/template/wishlist/view.phtml:56:
```

Comment: I will check more and provide good solution. I am sorry little busy on My work.

Comment: Sorry for delay ans. pretty busy on entire week. Your question very good question for applied Supee 9767 v2 peoples :). I like that.

Answer (score 1):

if `Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout`  in backend. It will check condition  `isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled()` in your core file `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`.

I am sure you are overwrite the `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php` in your checkout or third-party module.

```
if ($this->isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled() && !$this->_validateFormKey()) {
                return;
            }
```

So you need to add the above condition in your overwrite or third party module files for following action.

> saveBillingAction()
>
> saveShippingAction()
>
> saveShippingMethodAction()
>
> savePaymentAction()

**Note :** dont forgot to add `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>` in your themes.

```
 /app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
```

**Important :**
Any one overwrite checkout also check the condition in your file.

```
if ($this->isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled() && !$this->_validateFormKey()) {
                return;
            }
```

Comment: is this work? please let me know

Comment: if it is work please accept the ans :)