# checkout problem with 1.9.3.4 after upgrade

Tags: checkout, upgrade, magento-1.9.3.4

I have upgrade from 1.9.3.2 at 1.9.3.4. I do not installed any 9767 patches. 
checkout Process is blocked. 
The checkout process does not proceed from first step. 
how to solve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved. I have controll all file, not only my template, and i have put row  `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>` in every form. Now it's ok. thanks to all

Answer (score 3):

Its May be the issue with formkey:
Please check the formkeys with theme checkout files

patch 9767 adds form keys to the following forms:

Shipping cart form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
```

Multishipping billing checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
```

Multishipping shipping checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
```

Billing checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

Shipping checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
```

Payment checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
```

Shipping method checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
```

Persistent Billing checkout form:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

What to do:

If you're using with custom versions of those templates you'll have to update them by adding the following code into them:

getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>

Comment: where i need controll for formkey? I have template Ultimo ..

Comment: Please find the updated answer

Comment: Before this you have to revert the 9767 files and install 9767v2 files

Comment: @EwallTester he already has M1.9.3.4 so SUPEE-9767v2 is included. Nothing to revert here?

Comment: oh ok. in the question i didnot find revert...anyhow its ok

Comment: Thenks for your response: I have controll all file in all folder with form for existing row getBlockHtml('formkey') ?> into tag form
I have template Ultimo and in Folder app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/checkout/ I not found file with form

Comment: ok give formkey there this will fix your issue

Comment: correct @EwallTester, i thougth it's all ok with 1.9.3.4 but proccess checkout don't start

Comment: After upgrade to 1934, your custom theme will not have the formkeys... so as per the above answer you have to give <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?> EX: app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

Comment: I have update also file old for security. mabye probelm cache?

Answer (score 3):

With Magento 1.9.3.4 patch `SUPEE-9767 V2` is included ...

For your problem please read [Security Patch SUPEE-9767 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176958/46249).

Seems that you have no `formkey` in your template files:

Add

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

To

- `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

Comment: my pocess checkout it's onepage and in all form ther is roww formkey

Comment: @DigitaleNetwork If you adjusted all files refresch cache please.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have controlled all file also in other folder different of "template".. after i have refresh cache ad now it's correct

Comment: You welcome. Please accept an answer to close this. It can be your own too :)

Answer (score 1):

1.9.3.4 comes with patch changes pre-installed in this version. It is most probably the form key issue. If your checkout page is customized or not the default Magento one, then add formkey using code `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>` in different forms on checkout page like billing form, shipping form.

Comment: thanks for your response but I have controll all file in all folder with form for existing row getBlockHtml('formkey') ?> into tag form
I have template Ultimo and in Folder app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/checkout/ I not found file with form

Comment: @DigitaleNetwork If the file isn't there Magento has a fallback system to use base template. For this file there is nothing to do.