# Supee-9767 saveBilling returning 500 after v2 Patch applied to 1.9.2.3 (formkeys present)

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, billing

After applying the Version 2 patch I'm having a problem with the patch where it seems that `saveBilling()` is returning 500 server error on checkout.

This is onepage checkout and I do use PayPal plus if that matters.

When I look at the form data the **formkey** value is there. So the missing formkey issue doesn't seem to be related to that.

I can disable formkey requirement in the admin side and the problem remains.

My template DOES NOT HAVE any /checkout/ stuff in it, so there are no files to add the often mentioned formkey's too --- that I can find.

*Previously mentioned solutions I've tried:*

> 1. https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b

-- My template doesn't have a /checkout/ override so nothing to patch

> 2. [Security Patch SUPEE-9767 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues)

Been through this thread a dozen times without success.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

*** Update ****

I've chased the problem down to the following:

Call to undefined method Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::**isFormkeyValidationOnChecko‌utEnabled();**

*** I found this function in Action.php ***

Any thoughts on why they undefined method call occurring.

Comment: you can do some test. first change to default theme and check if it is work. the problem is in your theme. also check php error log.Please check and add your error log here.

Comment: Is `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js` overridden in your theme?  If so, you will need to make the same changes in that file in your theme.

Comment: is the issue resolved?

Comment: I'm working to get the information requested still.  The problem hasn't been resolved yet.

Comment: Call to undefined method Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled() is the problem here.  I did find the function defined in \controller\front\action.php   Any idea why its undefined?

Comment: Just something strange I noticed, if I copy paste your 'isFormkeyValidationOnChecko‌utEnabled' from your report, it contains some kind of hidden space character between 'Checko' and 'ut', it should be: 'isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled', this might cause the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution Follows***

Thank you everyone for pointing me in the right direction.  The problem ended up being that

**app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Front\Action.php**

was being overwritten at

**app\code\community\Mage\Core\Controller\Front\Action.php**

This old code was taking precedent over the patched Action.php which includes the new function **isFormkeyValidationOnChecko‌utEnabled();** and some other stuff.

In my case two solutions where available.

Solution 1: After inspecting the old Action.php it was found that this file was not required and simply deleting this file allowed the new version of Action.php to take over.

Solution 2: Was to copy the function isFormkeyValidationOnChecko‌utEnabled() and every other change made to Action.php over to the old Action.php to preserve any special behavior the template included in the first place.

Comment: Good you are resolved the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue may cause because of two things.

1. You are may be overwrite the `\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php`, this method is 
   not there isFormkeyValidationOnChecko‌​utEnabled();
2. compiler may be enable. clear cache and recompile again .