# which patch number user for 9767

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-9767

I am planning to install [patch SUPEE-9767](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download?_ga=2.267811790.1158683088.1501666189-2068246564.1496727858) in Magento 1.9.1.1

Guide me to know which version of patch I should install in Magento 1.9.1.1?

```
$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v2-2017-07-11-11-04-56.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Symlink.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
Hunk #3 succeeded at 450 (offset -23 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 350 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 366 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 413 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 442 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 481 (offset 1 line).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 282 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 159 with fuzz 2 (offset -29 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 87 (offset -1 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 146 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 578 (offset -23 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.6.1.1-1.6.0.6.1.2.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 498 (offset -2 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/head-simple.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 7 (offset -26 lines).
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 109 with fuzz 2.
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 78 with fuzz 1 (offset -6 lines).
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 91 with fuzz 2.
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 126 with fuzz 2.
can't find file to patch at input line 986
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
|index 9b32986..fe4be12 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 36 with fuzz 1 (offset -1 lines).
can't find file to patch at input line 1010
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
|index 7907ab3..3e3bcd3 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 43 with fuzz 1.
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 199 with fuzz 1.
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 78 with fuzz 1 (offset -6 lines).
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 93 with fuzz 2.
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 37 with fuzz 1 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 142 with fuzz 1.
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 201 with fuzz 1.
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1197 (offset -88 lines).
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 399 (offset -8 lines).
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
checking file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 417 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 964 (offset -15 lines).
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 82 with fuzz 2.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 268 (offset -5 lines).
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
checking file js/varien/payment.js
checking file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
Hunk #1 succeeded at 711 (offset 27 lines).
```

Comment: updated the comment please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download SUPEE-9767v2 for CE 1.9.1.0-1.9.3.0 (0.59 MB). it will work

```
Hunk #1 succeeded at 43 with fuzz 1.
```

The message you see means the file was successfully patched, fuzz 1 means Some lines had only spaces but they got trimmed to empty lines, so the patch file applied correctly, but with fuzz factors warnings display.

```
 app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
```

please check this two files is correctly updated.

Note: In SUPEE-9767  `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml(“formkey”) ?>` was added. if your overwrite the file in your theme please add formkey in your theme.

Comment: after install any issue please let me know i will provide solution :)

Comment: getting the above error while using that version

Comment: is it work Please let me know

Comment: I have both files under persistent folder app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml & shipping.phtml

Comment: okey No problem , Please check this files are overwrite in your theme. if overwrite please add $this->getBlockHtml(“formkey”) for your overwrite theme also :)

Comment: If it is work please accept the ans :)

Comment: yes rama its worked

Comment: After update billing.phtml and shipping.phtml, still not run,

Comment: Hi @zus check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues?answertab=active#tab-top need to apply formkey for some of theme files. here the question is different :)

Answer (score 0):

You have manually changed the `checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml` file

download magento fresh installation and apply and revert this file from original one and apply this patch

and copy this file to your themes directory and do your change