# Checkout one page doesn't load next step

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.4 and facing an issue with Onepage checkout. It's not moving to next step when I click on "Continue" button.

I didn't find any errors in browser console.

Site URL: http://handasia.net/en/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am assuming that there is missing `form_key` on checkout pages. You can add `form_key` using this code `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>` in template file.

Can you please check `form_key` in form? And add `form_key` if missing.

Comment: @AshokDubariya Thank you for pointing that out. Your assumption was correct and when I disable form key validation the issue disappear. I have added the form_key to all files listed here (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues?noredirect=1&lq=1) but "Continue" button still not moving to next step. Also I made sure that js files were updated as well.

Comment: I would appreciate it if anyone can recommend where else I need to check to solve this issue?

Comment: I am not able to create / register new account because of I'm assuming that there is missing `form_key` on this page https://handasia.net/en/customer/account/create/

Comment: So can you please provided me email address and password for login purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your help.

I was checking why registration wasn't working and while searching. I found another post mentioning how to enable "Template Path Hints" which I didn't know about. 
I used that to find registration and checkout templates that was missing form_key.