# Patch SUPEE-10415 applied but Form Key Validation message still appears

Tags: magento-1.9, form-key, supee-10415

Patched Magento Open Source 1.9.3.6 with SUPEE-10415.

Message:

`Formkey validation on checkout disabled. This may expose security risks. We strongly recommend to Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout in Admin / Security Section, for protect your own checkout process.` still appears.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

You still need to enable the form key validation on the checkout as per SUPEE-9767/Magento 1.9.3.6. Login to admin and go to:

`System > Configuration > Advanced/Admin > Security > Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout >> Yes`

**Warning**
You will need to ensure any custom templates have the formkey outputted otherwise your checkout process will not work.

Please refer to **Checkout form keys** on https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176958/41117 for more information

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added a patch and added a Form key in all checkout phtml files which is using form tag.

Go to `System->Configuration->Advanced->Admin and set Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout = Yes`
http://ift.tt/2Ao6mTE

If any checkout has any form key is missing then your checkout should not work correctly.