# White screen after customer login/post or creation of new account

Tags: magento-1.9, login, white-screen

I have just moved from a new server and updated from Magento `1.9.2.4` to `1.9.3.8`.

Everything is working as expected except for when a customer logs in on the front end.

It gets stuck on a **white screen**, if I click back it then redirects to teh account.

It also does the same on new account creations.

In the logs there are errors for

> "HEADERS ALREADY SENT:"

I have tried clearing cache and sessions several times.

Comment: [Security Patch SUPEE-9767](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues) added form-keys to many pages, and that is what your problem _sounds like_.  It is worth checking out the link above for more details, but if you are using a customized template for your customer login, the fallback file will override the patch's, and you will need to add a form-key.

Comment: What's the URL in the address bar of the browser when you get the white screen?